# Template Metaprogramming - I still don't get it :(

Tags: c++, templates, metaprogramming

I have a problem... I don't understand template metaprogramming.

The problem is, that I’ve read a lot about it, but it still doesn’t make much sense to me.

**Fact nr.1**: Template Metaprogramming is **faster**

```
template <int N>
struct Factorial 
{
    enum { value = N * Factorial<N - 1>::value };
};
 
template <>
struct Factorial<0> 
{
    enum { value = 1 };
};
 
// Factorial<4>::value == 24
// Factorial<0>::value == 1
void foo()
{
    int x = Factorial<4>::value; // == 24
    int y = Factorial<0>::value; // == 1
}
```

So this metaprogram is faster ... because of the constant literal.

**BUT**: Where in *the real world* do we have constant literals? Most programs I use react on user input.

**FACT nr. 2** : Template metaprogramming can accomplish **better maintainability.**

Yeah, the factorial example may be maintainable, but when it comes to complex functions, I and most other C++ programmers can't read them.

Also, the debugging options are very poor (or at least I don't know how to debug).

When does template metaprogramming make sense?

Comment: It never made much sense to me...

Comment: Don't feel bad, hardly anybody gets it.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Just as factorial is not a realistic example of recursion in non-functional languages, neither is it a realistic example of template metaprogramming. It's just the standard example people reach for when they want to show you recursion.

In writing templates for realistic purposes, such as in everyday libraries, often the template has to adapt what it does depending on the type parameters it is instantiated with. This can get quite complex, as the template effectively chooses what code to generate, conditionally. This is what template metaprogramming is; if the template has to loop (via recursion) and choose between alternatives, it is effectively like a small program that executes during compilation to generate the right code.

Here's a really nice tutorial from the boost documentation pages (actually excerpted from a [brilliant book](http://www.informit.com/store/product.aspx?isbn=0321227255), well worth reading).

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_39_0/libs/mpl/doc/tutorial/representing-dimensions.html

Comment: Good answer. +1
- I wish people had agreed on a better standard example. Generally, using metaprogramming to compute values is just pointless. It's enlightening as a learning exercise, when trying to figure out TMP, but not as a use case, and not as a selling point to convince people of how awesome the feature is.

Comment: I wouldn't write off value generation completely :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/699781/c-binary-constant-literal

Comment: Of course it can be useful, but it's not really the big selling point to convince people that the feature is worthwhile. The binary example is better than usual, but still, the obvious question is "why not just do it at runtime? It's not like it's prohibitively expensive." Is that really justification for layering another turing-complete language on top of C++? ;)

Comment: The way Stroustrup tells it, no one ever decided to do it, so there was no need for a justification! :) They just realised afterwards. The pieces are useful on their own, before you even put them together in a complex combination. But I agree with your point generally - it really becomes an interesting feature when you construct an internal DSL with it.

Comment: As usual, a comment from the downvoter might be interesting (but then again, it might not).

Comment: Absolutely. Your `value_type` example is much better as a starting point - it's an "if" rather than a "loop" and so exemplifies probably 90% of uses of template specialization. And for a more advanced example that mixes it up, I'd suggest people try working through boost's parameter library. Or maybe write their own (it's actually easier than understanding someone else's!)

Answer (score 15):

I use template mete-programming for SSE swizzling operators to optimize shuffles during compile time.

SSE swizzles ('shuffles') can only be masked as a byte literal (immediate value), so we created a 'mask merger' template class that merges masks during compile time for when multiple shuffle occur:

```
template <unsigned target, unsigned mask>
struct _mask_merger
{
    enum
    {
        ROW0 = ((target >> (((mask >> 0) & 3) << 1)) & 3) << 0,
        ROW1 = ((target >> (((mask >> 2) & 3) << 1)) & 3) << 2,
        ROW2 = ((target >> (((mask >> 4) & 3) << 1)) & 3) << 4,
        ROW3 = ((target >> (((mask >> 6) & 3) << 1)) & 3) << 6,

        MASK = ROW0 | ROW1 | ROW2 | ROW3,
    };
};
```

This works and produces remarkable code without generated code overhead and little extra compile time.

Answer (score 9):

> so this Metaprogram is faster ... beacause of the Constant Literal.
>   BUT : Where in the real World do we have constant Literals ?
>   Most programms i use react on user input.

That's why it's hardly ever used for values. Usually, it is used on types. using types to compute and generate new types.

There are many real-world uses, some of which you're already familiar with even if you don't realize it.

One of my favorite examples is that of iterators. They're mostly designed just with generic programming, yes, but template metaprogramming is useful in one place in particular:

To patch up pointers so they can be used as iterators. An iterator must expose a handful of typedef's, such as `value_type`. Pointers don't do that.

So code such as the following (basically identical to what you find in Boost.Iterator)

```
template <typename T>
struct value_type {
  typedef typename T::value_type type;
};

template <typename T>
struct value_type<T*> {
  typedef T type;
};
```

is a very simple template metaprogram, but which is very useful. It lets you get the value type of any iterator type T, whether it is a pointer or a class, simply by `value_type<T>::type`.

And I think the above has some very clear benefits when it comes to maintainability. Your algorithm operating on iterators only has to be implemented once. Without this trick, you'd have to make one implementation for pointers, and another for "proper" class-based iterators.

Tricks like `boost::enable_if` can be very valuable too. You have an overload of a function which should be enabled for a specific set of types only. Rather than defining an overload for each type, you can use metaprogramming to specify the condition and pass it to `enable_if`.

Earwicker already mentioned another good example, a framework for expressing physical units and dimensions. It allows you to express computations like with physical units attached, and enforces the result type. Multiplying meters by meters yields a number of square meters. Template metaprogramming can be used to automatically produce the right type.

But most of the time, template metaprogramming is used (and useful) in small, isolated cases, basically to smooth out bumps and exceptional cases, to make a set of types look and behave uniformly, allowing you to use generic programming more efficiently

Answer (score 9):

Seconding the recommendation for Alexandrescu's *Modern C++ Design*.

Templates really shine when you're writing a library that has pieces which can be assembled combinatorically in a "choose a Foo, a Bar and a Baz" approach, and you expect users to make use of these pieces in some form that is fixed at compile time. For example, I coauthored a data mining library that uses template metaprogramming to let the programmer decide what `DecisionType` to use (classification, ranking or regression), what `InputType` to expect (floats, ints, enumerated values, whatever), and what `KernelMethod` to use (it's a data mining thing). We then implemented several different classes for each category, such that there were several dozen possible combinations.

Implementing 60 separate classes to do this would have involved a lot of annoying, hard-to-maintain code duplication. Template metaprogramming meant that we could implement each *concept* as a code unit, and give the programmer a simple interface for instantiating combinations of these concepts at compile-time.

Dimensional analysis is also an excellent example, but other people have covered that.

I also once wrote some simple compile-time pseudo-random number generators just to mess with people's heads, but that doesn't really count IMO.

Comment: Messing with people's heads is one of the finest uses to which programming can be put! Don't underestimate the value of that. :p

Answer (score 5):

The factorial example is about as useful for real-world TMP as "Hello, world!" is for common programming: It's there to show you a few useful techniques (recursion instead of iteration, "else-if-then" etc.) in a very simple, relatively easy to understand example that doesn't have much relevance for your every-day coding. (When was the last time you needed to write a program that emitted "Hello, world"?)

TMP is about executing algorithms at compile-time and this implies a few obvious advantages:

- Since these algorithms  failing means your code doesn't compile, failing algorithms never make it to your customer and thus can't fail at the customer's. For me, during the last decade this was the single-most important advantage that led me to introduce TMP into the code of the companies I worked for.
- Since the result of executing template-meta programs is ordinary code that's then compiled by the compiler, all advantages of code generating algorithms (reduced redundancy etc.) apply.
- Of course, since they are executed at compile-time, these algorithms won't need any run-time and will thus run faster. TMP is mostly about compile-time computing with a few, mostly small, inlined functions sprinkled in between, so compilers have ample opportunities to optimize the resulting code.

Of course, there's disadvantages, too:

- The error messages can be horrible.
- There's no debugging.
- The code is often hard to read.

As always, you'll just have to weight the advantages against the disadvantages in every case.

As for a more useful *example*: Once you have grasped type lists and basic compile-time algorithms operating on them, you might understand the following:

```
typedef 
    type_list_generator< signed char
                       , signed short
                       , signed int
                       , signed long
                       >::result_type
    signed_int_type_list;

typedef 
    type_list_find_if< signed_int_type_list
                     , exact_size_predicate<8>
                     >::result_type
    int8_t;

typedef 
    type_list_find_if< signed_int_type_list
                     , exact_size_predicate<16>
                     >::result_type
    int16_t;

typedef 
    type_list_find_if< signed_int_type_list
                     , exact_size_predicate<32>
                     >::result_type
    int32_t;
```

This is (slightly simplified) actual code I wrote a few weeks ago. It will pick the appropriate types from a type list, replacing the `#ifdef` orgies common in portable code. It doesn't need maintenance, works without adaption on every platform your code might need to get ported to, and emits a compile error if the current platform doesn't have the right type.

Another example is this:

```
template< typename TFunc, typename TFwdIter >
typename func_traits<TFunc>::result_t callFunc(TFunc f, TFwdIter begin, TFwdIter end);
```

Given a function `f` and a sequence of strings, this will dissect the function's signature, convert the strings from the sequence into the right types, and call the function with these objects. And it's mostly TMP inside.

Answer (score 3):

Scott Meyers has been working on enforcing code constraints using TMP.

Its quite a good read:
http://www.artima.com/cppsource/codefeatures.html

In this article he introduces the concepts of Sets of Types (not a new concept but his work is based ontop of this concept). Then uses TMP to make sure that no matter what order you specify the members of the set that if two sets are made of the same members then they are equavalent. This requires that he be able to sort and re-order a list of types and compare them dynamically thus generating compile time errors when they do not match.

Comment: Actually his name is "Meyers". (Sorry for nitpicking.)

Answer (score 3):

Here's one trivial example, a binary constant converter, from a previous question here on StackOverflow:

[C++ binary constant/literal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/699781/c-binary-constant-literal)

```
template< unsigned long long N >
struct binary
{
  enum { value = (N % 10) + 2 * binary< N / 10 > :: value } ;
};
template<>
struct binary< 0 >
{
  enum { value = 0 } ;
};
```

Answer (score 3):

TMP does not necessarily mean faster or more maintainable code.  I used the boost [spirit](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_39_0/libs/spirit/classic/index.html) library to implement a simple SQL expression parser that builds an evaluation tree structure.  While the development time was reduced since I had some familiarity with TMP and lambda, the learning curve is a brick wall for "C with classes" developers, and the performance is not as good as a traditional LEX/YACC.

I see Template Meta Programming as just another tool in my tool-belt.  When it works for you use it, if it doesn't, use another tool.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you read [Modern C++ Design](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modern_C%2B%2B_Design) by Andrei Alexandrescu - this is probably one of the best books on real-world uses of C++ template metaprogramming; and describes many problems which C++ templates are an excellent solution.

Comment: Every C++ developer should read that book, but it's not all that helpful in answering the question, for the same reason that simply providing a link to Google is usually frowned upon. SO is supposed to be a place to find answers, not links to other resources where you might try searching instead.

Comment: The 3rd edition of Scott Meyers' Effective C++ also contains an example that's explained quite thoroughly. (Although that's about function overloading instead of meta functions and thus might not seem as "real TMP" at first.)

Answer (score 2):

TMP can be used from anything like ensuring dimensional correctness (Ensuring that mass cannot be divided by time, but distance can be divided by time and assigned to a velocity variable) to optimizing matrix operations by removing temporary objects and merging loops when many matrices are involved.

Comment: mass can be divided by time. The result just has to be of type "mass per time" ;)
But yeah, TMP can be used to enforce that.

Comment: Anything can be divided/multiplied by anything, it's addition/subtraction that trips people up.

Answer (score 2):

'static const' values work as well. And pointers-to-member. And don't forget the world of types (explicit and deduced) as compile-time arguments!

> BUT : Where in the real World do we have constant Literals ?

Suppose you have some code that has to run as fast as possible. It contains the critical inner loop of your CPU-bound computation in fact. You'd be willing to increase the size of your executable a bit to make it faster. It looks like:

```
double innerLoop(const bool b, const vector<double> & v)
{
    // some logic involving b

    for (vector::const_iterator it = v.begin; it != v.end(); ++it)
    {
        // significant logic involving b
    }

    // more logic involving b
    return ....
}
```

The details aren't important, but the use of 'b' is pervasive in the implementation.

Now, with templates, you can refactor it a bit:

```
template <bool b> double innerLoop_B(vector<double> v) { ... same as before ... }
double innerLoop(const bool b, const vector<double> & v)
{ return b ? innerLoop_templ_B<true>(v) : innerLoop_templ_B<false>(v) ); }
```

Any time you have a relatively small, discrete, set of values for a parameter you can *automatically* instantiate separate versions for them.

Consider the possiblities when 'b' is based on the CPU detection. You can run a differently-optimized set of code depending on run-time detection. All from the same source code, or you can specialize some functions for some sets of values.

As a concrete example, I once saw some code that needed to merge some integer coordinates. Coordinate system 'a' was one of two resolutions (known at compile time), and coordinate system 'b' was one of two different resolutions (also known at compile time). The target coordinate system needed to be the least common multiple of the two source coordinate systems. A library was used to compute the LCM at compile time and instantiate code for the different possibilities.