# how to make a function that takes binary argument?

Tags: c, binary

so i have this function that returns a binary representation in c:

```
long int int2bin(int d)
{
    int rem, pow = 1;
    long int b = 0; 
    while(d > 0) 
    {
        rem = d % 2 ;
        b += (pow * rem);
        d /= 2;
        pow *= 10;
    }

    return b;
}
```

so from this i was wondering how i might go about having a bin2int() function:

```
long int bin2int( bin b);
```

and you would use it like this:

```
bin2int(10011);
```

and i could this

```
printf("%i\n", bin2int(10011));
```

to get 19

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to represent the binary as a string?

Comment: probably yeah. i was just being general. i guess representing it as a string would be the only way to do it other than making a custom type?

Comment: See [Can I use a binary literal in C or C++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2611764/can-i-use-a-binary-literal-in-c-or-c).

Comment: The obvious answer seems to be to use the same type as the return type of your function above, i.e. long int.

Answer (score 2):

Just replace the `2`s and `10` in your function with, respectively, `10`s and `2`.

Answer (score 1):

Binary, hex and decimal are simply different ways of representing the same number. For instance all these representations equate to the same - 27 in decimal = 0x1b in hex = 0b11011 in binary.

You can specify the number using any format as an argument to a function expecting a number (int, unsigned int, even char etc).

For instance to print your binary number you could do `printf("%i\n", 0b10011)` which would give you the number 19. You could write the statement as `printf("%i\n", 19)` (decimal) or `printf("%i\n", 0x13)` (hex).

Comment: `0b10011` is not standard C. Some compilers support it as an extension.

Comment: do you know which compilers? im using MSVC (and it doesnt support it, at least not by default).

Comment: @interjay thanks. I thought as much. I remember seeing code from a long time ago that used macros B8(1011), B16(10001000) to define binary numbers. But now most compilers appear to support the 0b notation right? Or is gcc the exception

Comment: @scruff you could try the bitset class - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2f93c55z(v=VS.80).aspx

Comment: @arunkumar thanks but i dont really wanna go mixing c++ into this. anyway i just tested gcc and it understands 0b10101 no problems. cool.

Answer (score 0):

In pseudo code:

```
int result = 0;
int ci = 1;
string s = stringof(10011).reverse();
for(int z=0; z < s.length; z++,ci = ci * 2)
{
   if(s[z] == '1')
      result += ci;
}
```