# Enter binary instead of hex

Tags: c

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can I use a binary literal in C or C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2611764/can-i-use-a-binary-literal-in-c-or-c)

In C I can write

```
uint32_t a = 0x40022000;
```

using hex. Can I do something similar by entering binary digits?

Comment: `0b100110...` does work?

Comment: Why would you ? If it's flags you are looking to implement, use something like `#define FLAG_ON(a, flag_num) ((a) |= (1 << flag_num))` `#define FLAG_OFF(a, flag_num) ((a) &= ~(1 << flag_num))`, `FLAG_ON(a, 3)` will give you a = binary 00001000

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can't do that with standard C, but some compilers such as [gcc](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Binary-constants.html#Binary-constants) supports an extension that allows you to write something like

```
uint32_t a = 0b11010101110101;
```

Comment: Don't use non-standard extensions however. They make your code unportable. gcc extensions in particular should be avoided. Unless perhaps if you are writing something intimately associated with the Linux OS, where no other compiler than gcc will ever be used.

Comment: @Lundin: To be fair, clang also supports it.

Comment: @lundin: while I mostly agree, it is more important to avoid *especially* MSVC extensions than gcc ones. At least gcc supports a lot of platforms.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible. In (ANSI) C you can enter either decimal, hexadecimal or octal digits. Use a converter to convert your binary number to a hex. A standard calculator with scientific capabilities should be enough.

Comment: Why use a calculator when you're *programming* a giant calculator? Just write a function that converts a string of binary digits to a numeric type.