# How to check if a hex number is equal to a specific binary number?

Tags: c, binary, hex

Hi I'm trying to do something which should be simple, but I can't figure it out. 
I have a pointer to an array of unsigned chars, and I get the first element, which is a hex number. I want to convert it to binary so I can check if it's equal to a number such as 0x01101000.

```
      unsigned char arr[] = {0x25};  //just for example. I am actually using *arr.
      unsigned char byte = arr[0];
      if(( byte & 0x01101000) == //not sure if this is the right way to proceed
```

Would appreciate some help! Thanks!!

Comment: The C language has no construct to express binary literals. Also, all numbers in a computer are binary in the end, which means that just comparing any two integers actually are comparing two binary numbers.

Comment: `0x01101000` is a hexadecimal number, you do know that? The binary representation would be `1000100000001000000000000`.

Comment: Numbers are all in binary, whatever kind of literal you use. Do you really want to build a number whose hexadecimal representation would give 25 if misinterpreted as binary?

Comment: Oops, I'm not looking for binary. I guess I just want to compare 2 hex numbers then? In that case, will if(byte == 0x01101000) give me the correct result?

Comment: You'll have to do the conversion by hand. Make a function for that.

Comment: In my example, when I print byte using                          printf("%02x\n ", byte);  it prints 25.

Comment: If you want to check if the value is equal to the binary number 01101000 , just convert it to hex and do if (whatever == 0x68)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2612556/762123) answer.

> If you are using GCC then you can use GCC extension for this: int x = 0b00010000;

So in your case, it would be:

```
if( byte == 0b01101000 )
...
```

Be sure to put only 8 bits in your literal though.

Comment: Thanks. Can I use == to check for equality?

Comment: @user2057841 fixed it. Different operators serve different purposes. Refer to http://stackoverflow.com/a/6092250/762123 for more details on bitwise operators.

Comment: @user2057841, you'd be better off using hex notation inside your program, it will be more portable. The 0b notation will only be useful when using GCC.