# Why C compiler wouldn't accept this conditional assignment?

Tags: c, iar

I was wondering why binary numbers can't be used with bitwise operators?

```
//works
msgSize = (*(msgbody+1) & 0x80)?*(msgbody+5):*(msgbody+3); 

//doesn't compile
msgSize = (*(msgbody+1) & 0b10000000)?*(msgbody+5):*(msgbody+3);
```

Comment: I presume you're programming with gcc... C doesn't have binary literals.

Comment: @modifiablelvalue you were first :) I'm working with IAR (not sure what compiler it uses). Binary literals work fine with Clang setup  for ObjC.

Comment: Irrelevant. An SSCCE might look like [this](http://ideone.com/T050u3). As you can see from my SSCCE, there are no binary literals in C.

Comment: Put it as an answer. I'll mark it answered. My error code looks different. My guess IAR is not GCC based.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can I use a binary literal in C or C++?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2611764/can-i-use-a-binary-literal-in-c-or-c)

Comment: No, IAR has nothing to do with gcc.

Comment: @JesperE That is what I said 2 two comments above.

Comment: You said "guess". I wanted to clarify and remove the guessing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Binary literals aren't supported in C; If they're available, they're an extension. I would suggest that your compiler is emitting an error because it doesn't recognise the binary literal `0b10000000`. Hence, your compiler probably emits an error on this, too:

```
int main(void) {
    int msgSize = 0b10000000;
    return 0;
}
```

I would suggest using `0x80` or `1 << 7` instead.