# Why doesn't C have binary literals?

Tags: c, syntax, binary, literals

I am frequently wishing I could do something like this in c:

```
val1 &= 0b00001111; //clear high nibble
val2 |= 0b01000000; //set bit 7
val3 &= ~0b00010000; //clear bit 5
```

Having this syntax seems like an incredibly useful addition to C with no downsides that I can think of, and it seems like a natural thing for a low level language where bit-twiddling is fairly common.

Edit: I'm seeing some other great alternatives but they all fall apart when there is a more complex mask. For example, if `reg` is a register that controls I/O pins on a microcontroller, and I want to set pins 2, 3, and 7 high at the same time I could write `reg = 0x46;` but I had to spend 10 seconds thinking about it (and I'll likely have to spend 10 seconds again every time I read those code after a not looking at it for a day or two) or I could write `reg = (1 << 1) | (1 << 2) | (1 << 6);` but personally I think that is way less clear than just writing `reg = 0b01000110;' I can agree that it doesn't scale well beyond 8 bit or maybe 16 bit architectures though. Not that I've ever needed to make a 32 bit mask.

Comment: it has hex, which in my opinion is even better, if you spend 10 minutes getting a feel for the relationship

Comment: Should that last comment read "clear bit 4"? (Or better yet, "clear bit 3", since programmers should count from zero by default?)

Comment: IMHO, because there's hex. Much more easy to programmer use than binary numbers. It's very error-prone. Not matter how experient you is.

Comment: Did you already see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2611764/315052)?

Comment: C has "binary" literals, but only 2 of them: 0, 1.  ;-)

Comment: For what it's worth, [C++14 will have these](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16334024/).

Comment: We have hex literals. All of your examples are about bit masking. I have no problem figuring out which bit is being turned on/off/whatever when I read `0x80`.

Comment: Your comments are wrong: instruction 1: set all bits in the low nibble, instruction 2: clear every bit exept bit 6 (not bit 7, bit start with 0), instruction 3: set every bit except bit 4 (again not bit 5)

Comment: `#define B00000000 0` `#define B00000001 1` `#define B00000010 2` `#define B00000011 3` ... `#define B10100100 0xA4` ... possibly with a cast to `unsigned char`.

Comment: @chux: `0` actually an *octal* literal.

Comment: @AnT: more precisely, `0` is an *octal-constant*

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Binary literals?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/537303/binary-literals)

Comment: C23 now supports binary literal integer constants:  https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/integer_constant
You can use either 0b00001111 or 0B00001111.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like [C23](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C23_(C_standard_revision)#Constants) now has binary literals.

Comment: C23 now supports binary literal integer constants:  https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/integer_constant
You can use either 0b00001111 or 0B00001111.

Answer (score 61):

According to [Rationale for International Standard - Programming Languages C](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/C99RationaleV5.10.pdf) §6.4.4.1 *Integer constants*

> A proposal to add binary constants was rejected due to lack of precedent and insufficient utility.

It's not in standard C, but GCC supports it as an extension, prefixed by `0b` or `0B`:

```
 i = 0b101010;
```

See [here](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Binary-constants.html#Binary-constants) for detail.

Comment: Thats awesome but I'm not using  GCC :( do you know what its not in the standard?

Comment: @Drew See the update. In another word, the committee thinks its usage can be covered by hex constants, I think.

Comment: Sometimes I think the people write standards don't actually code anything in the language they are standardizing. That, or they are all part of the same niche tech space and can't fathom that anyone uses the language for anything other than what they use it for.

Answer (score 22):

This is what pushed [hexadecimal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexadecimal) to be... hexadecimal. The "... *primary use of hexadecimal notation is a human-friendly representation of binary-coded values in computing and digital electronics ...*". It would be as follows:

```
val1 |= 0xF;
val2 &= 0x40;
val3 |= ~0x10;
```

**Hexadecimal:**

1. One hex digit can represent a nibble (4 bits or half an octal).
2. Two hex digits can represent a byte (8 bits).
3. Hex is much more compact when scaling to larger masks.

With some practice, converting between hexadecimal and binary will become much more natural. Try writing out your conversions by hand and not using an online bin/hex notation converter -- then in a couple days it will become natural (and quicker as a result).

**Aside:** Even though binary literals are not a C standard, if you compile with GCC it is possible to use binary literals, they should be prefixed with '0b' or '0B'. See the official documentation [here](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Binary-constants.html) for further information. Example:

```
int b1 = 0b1001; // => 9
int b2 = 0B1001; // => 9
```

Comment: Yes that is what I always end up doing instead, but I always have to do a bunch of calculations in my to remember what binary is what in hax. Especially if I want to eg. clear the lowest 6 bits. And I agree that binary literals would get long for 32 bit platforms, but in that case you can just not use them.

Comment: Thinking in hex becomes second nature after a little practice. Hex also has the advantage that it is easier to read than binary.

Comment: @Drew, I understand your point of view as it may be visually much easier to think about for smaller masks. Once you have practiced enough it will come fairly natural (as everything comes in life). I recommend doing all calculations out by hand and double check yourself on a calculator when creating masks so that you can get better and converting between the two notations.

Comment: How much mental math does it really take to imagine the binary value represented by a hex number? Of all the operations/calculations that a good programmer needs to do in their head, I think this one is one of the simplest.

Comment: +1 I don't knew really that's the primary use of hex notation. Good know!

Comment: please change "4 bytes" to "4 bits" in bullet point 1.
One nibble is 4 bits, not bytes.

Answer (score 16):

All of your examples can be written even more clearly:

```
val1 &= (1 << 4) - 1; //clear high nibble
val2 |= (1 << 6); //set bit 6
val3 &=~(1 << 3); //clear bit 3
```

(I have taken the liberty of fixing the comments to count from zero, like Nature intended.)

Your compiler will fold these constants, so there is no performance penalty to writing them this way. And these are easier to read than the `0b...` versions.

Comment: @Jerry Well, that will teach me not to stop thinking after the first error. Thanks

Comment: If we take into account endianness, is `(1 << 4) - 1` really the same as `0xF` ? ... maybe not.

Comment: @AbrahamSanchez: Yes, it is exactly the same on all platforms. Arithmetic operations like left shift are defined independently of endianness. (In fact, endianness is not even detectable unless you cast a pointer or use a union.)

Comment: @Nemo or a array, or a struct, or any other variable. As long as you use some hack like the memcpy one everything is possible.

Comment: @YoYoYonnY: All of those require that you "cast a pointer or use a union", as I said.

Comment: @Nemo I think 'dereference' is a better term, but you're right, I'm sorry. I was just trying to point out that you can use any memory type to check endianness using a hack like memcpy or memset or something similair, as long as its size is over 1 byte)

Answer (score 12):

I think readability is a primary concern. Although low-level, it's human beings who read and maintain your code, not machine.

Is it easy for you to figure out that you mistakenly typed `0b1000000000000000000000000000000(0x40000000)`, where you really mean `0b10000000000000000000000000000000(0x80000000)` ?

Comment: This seems like the best reason so far. Still, though, you don't have to use binary in those cases. And how often do you make a 32 bit mask anyway?

Comment: Since they have a better alternative(hexdecimal) in most cases, I guess the committee just close the door to such mistakes by not providing it.

Comment: but this make more hard to understand some other cases, for example if that is a register where bit may have different meaning, having to take out the calculator to see what bit are enabled/disabled is just a complication. This is a common case when dealing with i2c/spi sensors.

Comment: @lesto, That's where hex form are mostly used. It's easy to tell the binary code from hex.

Comment: just because you can write unreadable code with a feature, it is not a reason to not allow it. you can always write unreadable code with every language if you want.

Comment: you say "It's easy to tell the binary code from hex" but your question lives upon the premise that its hard to tell the hex from the binary. I dont really buy that. Even if I would, just because it can be misused (you wouldnt really use a binary literal when it has ~20 digits) doesnt mean that it can help sometimes

Answer (score 3):

"For example, if reg is a register that controls I/O pins on a microcontroller"

I can't help thinking this is a bad example. Bits in control registers have specific functions (as will any devices connected to individual IO bits).

It would be far more sensible to provide symbolic constants for bit patterns in a header file, rather than working out the binary within the code. Converting binary to hexadecimal or octal is trivial, remembering what happens when you write 01000110 to an IO register is not, particularly if you don't have the datasheet or circuit diagram handy.

You will then not only save those 10 seconds trying to work out the binary code, but maybe the somewhat longer time trying to work out what it does!

Answer (score 2):

I recommend C macros in C for this to avoid compiler warnings or other problems. Instead of 0x I use Ox (like in "Ohio").

```
#define Ob00000001 1
#define Ob10000000 (1 << (8-1))
#define Ob00001111 15
#define Ob11110000_8 (Ob00001111 << (8 - 4))
#define Ob11110000_16 (Ob00001111 << (16 - 4))
#define Ob11110000_32 (((uint32_t) Ob00001111) << (32 - 4))
#define Ob11110000_64 (((uint64_t) Ob00001111) << (64 - 4))
#define Ox0F Ob00001111
#define OxF0 Ob11110000_8
#define OxF000 Ob11110000_16
#define OxF0000000 Ob11110000_32
#define OxF000000000000000 Ob11110000_64

int main() {
    #define Ob00001110 14
    // bitwise operations work
    if (Ob00001110 == (Ob00001111 & ~Ob00000001)) {
        printf("true\n");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

My approach was:

```
/* binmacro.h */

#define BX_0000 0
#define BX_0001 1
#define BX_0010 2
#define BX_0011 3
#define BX_0100 4
#define BX_0101 5
#define BX_0110 6
#define BX_0111 7
#define BX_1000 8
#define BX_1001 9
#define BX_1010 A
#define BX_1011 B
#define BX_1100 C
#define BX_1101 D
#define BX_1110 E
#define BX_1111 F

#define BIN_A(x) BX_ ## x

#define BIN_B(x,y) 0x ## x ## y
#define BIN_C(x,y) BIN_B(x,y)

#define BIN_B4(x,y,z,t) 0x ## x ## y ## z ## t
#define BIN_C4(x,y,z,t) BIN_B4(x,y,z,t)

#define BIN(x,y) BIN_C(BIN_A(x),BIN_A(y))
#define BIN4(x,y,z,t) BIN_C4(BIN_A(x),BIN_A(y),BIN_A(z),BIN_A(t))

/*---- test ... ---*/

BIN(1101,0100)

BIN4(1101,0010,1100,0101)
```

Which preprocesses to ...

```
$  cpp binmacro.h
0xD4

0xD2C5
```

Answer (score 0):

Binary is most useful when setting specific outputs on a controller. I use a hack which is technically illegal but nonetheless always works. If you just need to turn an LED on it offends every sensibility to use a whole int, or even a char for the job. Don't forget we're probably not talking about the ultimate in compilation sophistication for these things. So, for individual intelligibility combined with group control I use bitfields :-

```
struct DEMAND
{
    unsigned int dOil   :   1; // oil on
    unsigned int dAir   :   1; // air on
    unsigned int dHeat  :   1; // heater on
    unsigned int dMtr1  :   1; // motor 1 on
    unsigned int dMtr2  :   1; // motor 2 on
    unsigned int dPad1  :   10;// spare demand o/p's
    unsigned int dRunCycle: 1; // GO !!!!
    unsigned int dPad2  :   15;// spare o/p's
    unsigned int dPowerOn:  1; // Power on
}DemandBF;
```

They're easily addressed when used singly, or for more thorough control they can be treated as an unsigned int in flagrant disregard of K&R:-

```
void *bitfPt = &DemandBF;
unsigned int *GroupOuts = (unsigned int *)bitfPt;

DemandBF.dAir = 1;   // Clearly describes what's turning on
DemandBF.dPowerOn = 1;

*GroupOuts ^= 0x04; // toggle the heater

*GroupOuts = 0; // kill it all
```

It's always worked for me, it's probably not portable, but then who actually ports something like this anyhow? Give it a go.

Comment: " but then who actually ports something like this anyhow?" People who change compiler for the same hardware. Roughly 100% of all embedded systems programmers have to do that at some point in their career.

Answer (score 0):

Since C++14 the standard includes the binary literals just like you suggested:

> binary-literal is the character sequence 0b or the character sequence 0B followed by one or more binary digits (0, 1)
>
> int b = 0b101010;

There is also a way to declare your own custom literals since C++11. The reasons, why the binary literals were not in the standard initially, are no longer important.

Answer (score -1):

The following is limited to 8 bits, although it should be straightforward to extend. While it does not result in a C literal, it does result in a compile time constant.

```
#define B_(X) B8_("00000000" #X)
#define B8_(X) B8__(X+sizeof(X)-9)
#define B8__(X) \
        (B___((X), 7) | B___((X), 6) | B___((X), 5) | B___((X), 4) | \
         B___((X), 3) | B___((X), 2) | B___((X), 1) | B___((X), 0))
#define B___(X, I) (((X)[7-(I)] - '0') << (I))
```

The following function is compiled into code that returns the constant `18`.

```
int test(void) {
    return B_(10010);
}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VZBLC8IwEITv@RWDHsyikdRXFT315smDl4JKqTXVXlqwUcTHb69bUWoWQvLNDmGYfVyeqiqJLRaLPp44JgnUjQ/UqoTixxqqgBLtg0mz3CCIZEgIppFs6e@00A6pMUx/Dr67ZXY3RcqCmjmWj2cr8B0ZRCyx1oNPHKPBiYtjF0c1Nt/8bYauceCi56Kmv3C1GvawJMh6u/GVXNKOG@noDnFNYCQhstzCmtLKa5EdCI9PiLOxl3Nel@Rp7Wmai5foV9Ub)

If performance is not an issue, you can do something simpler:

```
#define B_(x) strtoull(#x, 0, 2)
```

Comment: This is going to do a runtime string decode, three times, every time this code is run. That's not going to do well for performance.

Comment: @DavidGiven, it is trivial for a compiler to optimize the values to compile-time constants. No runtime decoding is performed.