# Why direct binary input/output is not allowed in C?

Tags: c

We can input decimal, octal and hexadecimal numbers using scanf. We can output decimal, octal, hexadecimal using printf.. Why not binary numbers? why they are excluded?

Comment: Same reason that base 6 and base 51 are excluded?

Comment: It's never about "not allowed"; you can code it yourself. It's about "Will this be significantly helpful to enough people to justify its inclusion in the library"... and the answer for this example is "no".

Comment: Duplicate?! [Why doesn't C have binary literals?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18244726/why-doesnt-c-have-binary-literals)

Comment: Look up `strtol` , it is in the standard library. One of the arguments is the base of the number system.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because any competent programmer can easily do binary number output and input himself, it's too verbose, and hexadecimal is just as good for flags and an easy transformation?

Comment: Which is the reason that is _only_ a supporting argument. The meat is in verbosity, feature creep, and already including a format humans can easily transform. BTW: Many are of the opinion that including octal was a grave mistake. It is rarely used by intent.

Comment: confident that octal was in greater usage than hexadecimal _back in the day_ of nascent C.  Hexadecimal was the new kid on the block and part of a successful feature creep.  I agree octal has limited uses today.