# How to declare a 16 Binary Bit Character in C/C++?

Tags: c++, c, literals

Everybody knows that if you declare a 8 bit value, you can do something like

```
int a = B10001110;
```

like that vut I dont know how to declare it in 16 bit, I did something like

```
int b = B1000000100001111;
```

but this gives me error. Is there something I can do about this? I want this 16 bit format declaration.

Comment: C or C++? There's a big difference here, for this case.

Comment: `Everybody knows` no, most people don't know that. `B10001110` is not an 8-bit value in either C or C++

Comment: Binary literals (starting with 0b) were standardized in c++14. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2611764/can-i-use-a-binary-literal-in-c-or-c

Comment: _but this gives me error_... sigh, which error??

Comment: In most implementations, use __unsigned short__ for 16 bits.

Comment: It's an interesting quirk of English that every statement which starts with "everybody knows" is false.

Comment: @molbdnilo: Everybody knows that.

Comment: @molbdnilo Why is that specific for English (apart from the fact that these words are English)?

Comment: [C] Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/18244726/694576

Answer (score 6):

C++14 allows you to use a *binary literal* of the form

```
int b = 0b1000000100001111;
```

The *type* of the literal follows the same rules as for hexadecimal literals. This is **not** standard C, although some C compilers allow it as an extension.

Your `B` notation is neither standard C nor standard C++.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you could use this?

```
strtol("1000000100001111", NULL, 2);
```

At least it's standard C.

Comment: And wickedly expensive.

Comment: @Bathsheba Indeed, but it might be something to consider depending on the application.