# Change 4 middle bits of a byte in C

Tags: c, bit-manipulation

I'm trying to change the 4 middle bits of a byte to correspond to the High nibble of another byte:

Suppose we start with:

```
In = 0bABCDEFGH
Out = 0bXXXXXXXX // Some random byte
```

I want:

```
Out = 0bXXABCDXX
```

Leaving whatever other bits were in `Out`'s extremes unchanged.

How can I do this?

**Note:** The 'X' represents any bit, 0 or 1, just to distinguish what came from the input.

I got to:

```
(0b00111100 & (IN>>2)) = 0b00ABCD00
```

, which filters the high nibble and centers it but then what? How can I move it to `Out`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

simple:

```
out &= 0b11000011;
out |= (in >> 2 & 0b00111100);
```

`out &= 0b11000011` sets `out` to `0bxx0000xx` preserving 2 most significant bits and 2 least significant bits. `in >> 2` shifts input by 2 giving us `0xYYABCDEF`, `YY` could be `00` or `11` depending on what `A` is. To get rid of `YY` and `EF` we do `& 0b00111100`.

As pointed by @JB `0B` is not standard notation, thus you should use something else, most preferably hex `0x` notation. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18244726/why-doesnt-c-have-binary-literals) for more info.

Thus using hex this would be:

```
out &= 0xC3;
out |= (in >> 2 & 0x3C)
```

here is conversion table

```
`0xf` is `0b1111`
`0x3` is `0b0011`
`0xc` is `0b1100`
```

Comment: It can be reduced to 4 operations instead of 5.

Comment: This `out &= 0b00111100` should be `out |= 0b00111100` shouldn't it?

Answer (score 4):

Assuming `in` and `out` are `unsigned char`, and that `CHAR_BIT == 8`:

```
out = (out & 0xC3) | ((in >> 2) & 0x3C);
```

i.e. 4 operations in total.

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple alternatives.  From a high-level perspective, you could

- force the four middle bits of `Out` **off**, prepare a mask from `In` as show in your question, and combine `Out` and mask via bitwise OR (`|`)
- force the four middle bits of `Out` **off**, prepare a mask from `In` as show in your question, and combine `Out` and mask via bitwise EXCLUSIVE OR (`^`)
- force the four middle bits of `Out` **on**, prepare a mask from `In` similarly to how you do now, but with the outer bits on, and combine `Out` and mask via bitwise AND (`&`)
- use a series of shifts, masks, and addition or bitwise OR operations to build up the wanted result section by section

Forcing bits off is achieved by bitwise AND with a mask that has 0s at (only) the positions you want to turn off.

Forcing bits on is achieved by bitwise OR with a mask that has 1s at (only) the positions you want to turn on.

You already seem to have a handle on shifting, though you do need to be careful there if you happen to be shifting objects of signed types.  Prefer to use unsigned types for bit manipulation wherever possible.