# assigning a variable using binary format - 0B causing error in ARM Keil uVision

Tags: arm, embedded, cortex-m, keil, armcc

I am workin on a project with TM4C123GH6PM micro-controller using keil uvision version 4.7. When I assign a value to a variable in binary format like the following:

```
unsigned char tmp = 0b11000011;
```

and then I build the project, the following error appears:

> expected a ";"

When I change the format to hex -using 0X- or Decimal, the error disappears.

doesn't the compiler in Keil uVision support the binary format?

Comment: What did the Keil documentation say?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ANSI C doesn't specify a syntax for binary literals. Keil compilers follow the ANSI C standard, and their manual usually record any deviations or extensions.

A previous discussion on this can be found here [Why doesn't C have binary literals?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18244726/why-doesnt-c-have-binary-literals)

Comment: thanks for your clarification. Seems ARMCC compiler doesn't use an extension to support the binary format.

Answer (score 1):

The Keil Arm v5 (ARMCC) compiler does not support binary literals.  But the Keil Arm V6 (ARMCLANG) compiler *does* support binary literals.  The Arm v6 compiler option is available with Keil MDK v5.12 and later.  You may need to port some of your code to switch compiler versions ([Migration Guide](https://www.keil.com/appnotes/files/apnt_298.pdf)).

Answer (score 1):

Open the "Options for target" --> switch to "C/C++" tab --> add `--gnu` in "Misc Controls" textbox.

Codes like `int a = 0b101010;` compile with no error.

I am using MDK 5.18 and ARMCC V5.06 update1 (build 61)