# How can I clear half a byte from a number

Tags: c, bit-manipulation

I know I can clear a single bit by using the bitwise operator &

```
number &= ~(1 << x);
```

But how would I be able to clear either the upper or lower half of a byte?
For example, number = 99

99  = 0110 0011 and clearing the upper half we get 0000 0011

Comment: Use masking techniques as in [Link][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28231740/rational-comparison-of-bits/28233250#28233250

Answer (score 2):

Just AND the byte with the mask you need: to clear the upper four bits, use `n & 0x0F`, to clear the lower four bits, use `n & 0xF0`.

Answer (score 1):

You could say `number &= 15;`. 15 is represented as `0000 1111` in binary which means the leading/upper 4 bits would be cleared away.

Likewise, to clear the trailing/lower 4 bits, you could then say `number &= 240` because 240 is represented as `1111 0000` in binary.

For example, let's say `number = 170` and we want to clear away the leading/upper four bits. `170` is represented as `1010 1010` in binary. So, if we do `number &= 15`, we get:

```
  1010 1010
& 0000 1111
-------------
  0000 1010
```

*(`0000 1010` is `10` in binary)*

Supposing, again, `number = 170` and we want to clear the trailing/lower four bits, we can say: `number &= 240`. When we do this, we get:

```
  1010 1010
& 1111 0000
-------------
  1010 0000
```

*(`1010 0000` is `160` in binary)*

Answer (score 0):

You want to do an `and` with the bit-pattern showing what you want to keep.

So for your case:

```
number &= 0xf;
```

As `0xf` is `0000 1111`.

This is sometimes referred to as a "mask".

Answer (score 0):

Clear lower half:

```
number &= ~0xF;
```

Higher half:

```
number &= ~0xF0;
```

The above works work int types. For larger types, you need to extend mask accordingly, for example:

```
number &= ~UINT64_C(0xF0);
```