# How can integer variable be initialized with the binary number in C?

Tags: c

We initialize octal by putting 0 as prefix and hexadecimal as 0x. How can we initialize an int  variable in binary number? Is there any access specifier in C for binary number? 
e.g %o for octal and %x for hexadecimal number.

Comment: [Can I use a binary literal in C or C++?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2611764/can-i-use-a-binary-literal-in-c-or-c) and [Is there a printf converter to print in binary format?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/111928/is-there-a-printf-converter-to-print-in-binary-format) and [Binary constants using the ‘0b’ prefix](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Binary-constants.html) for more info.

Answer (score 13):

Recent versions of GCC provide an extension to the C standard. Use `0b` or `0B` to prefix a bit series like:

```
int i = 0b0101010;
```

Comment: I use gcc version 4.7.2. Both 0b and 0B works. But what is the access specifier to print binary number?

Comment: @Harsh: As far as I know there is none. However gcc overs you the possibility to roll your own: http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Customizing-Printf.html#Customizing-Printf

Answer (score 2):

`int a = 0b0001010;` for [GCC extension](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Binary-constants.html)