# Why is 0x00000100 = 256?

Tags: c, binary

Shouldn't 0x00000100 = 4.

I understand that 0x00000001 = 1 since 2^0 and 0x00000010 = 2 since 2^1. What is wrong with my thinking?

```
initVariable(&variable1, "variable1", "1, 2, 3", 0x00000100);

assertIntegerEquals(variable1.address, 4); // 0x00000100 = 4?
```

My assertion fails because it says that 256 != 4

Comment: `0x` is the prefix commonly used for hexadecimal (base-16) numbers, not binary (base-2). Also, 0x00000010 is 16 since 16^1.

Comment: Shouldn't 0000 0100 = 8 and 0000 0010 = 4

Comment: @jonnh, 00000100 is 8.  But the OP is talking hex: 0x00000010 is 16, not 2.

Comment: @Joe, @JonnyHenly: `00000100` is `64`, at least in C.

Comment: @Joe oh yea I meant 8 :)

Comment: And by 8, I mean 4.  0001 = 1, 0010 = 2, 0100 = 4, 1000 = 8.  :)

Comment: @Joe: Again, at least in C `0010` is `8` and `0100` is `64` and `1000`is `1000` is `1000`, same for `1`.

Comment: @alk, yes, for octal interpretation.  My point is: the numbers in the OP's question are shown as hex but he's interpreting as binary.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Numbers that begin with `0x` are interpreted as hexadecimal (base 16) in C.

So `0x10 == 16`, and `0x100 == 256`, `0x10000 == 65536`, etc.

Powers of two are:

- 2<sup>0</sup> = 0x1
- 2<sup>1</sup> = 0x2
- 2<sup>2</sup> = 0x4
- 2<sup>3</sup> = 0x8
- 2<sup>4</sup> = 0x10
- 2<sup>5</sup> = 0x20
- 2<sup>6</sup> = 0x40
- 2<sup>7</sup> = 0x80
- 2<sup>8</sup> = 0x100

Answer (score 11):

No, the `0x` means hexadecimal (i.e. base-16) and not binary, which is what you seem to be confusing it with.

If you want to use binary literals in your code, then see [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2611764/can-i-use-a-binary-literal-in-c-or-c), which mentions the gcc extension that allows `0b00000100` to be used to represent `4` in binary.

Answer (score 8):

`0x00000100` is in base-16 because `0x` prefix means you are using hexadecimal notation.

So `0x00000001` = 1*16<sup>0</sup> = 1, `0x00000010` = 1*16<sup>1</sup>, `0x00000100` = 1*16<sup>2</sup> = 256 and `0x00000123` = 1*16<sup>2</sup> + 2*16<sup>1</sup> + 3*16<sup>0</sup> = 256 + 32 + 3 = 291

To play with base-2, base-10 and base-16 notation, you can try this site: http://www.mathsisfun.com/binary-decimal-hexadecimal-converter.html

Comment: That is indeed a nice answer.

Answer (score 6):

The `0x` prefix means [hexadecimal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexadecimal)

Answer (score 3):

0x00000100 (hex) = 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0001 0000 0000 (binary) = 256 (decimal)

Answer (score 1):

`0x` prefix is hexadecimal `0x00000100 = 256  base 16`

00000100 = 000001<sup>2</sup>0<sup>1</sup>0<sup>0</sup>

= 1 * 16<sup>2</sup> + 0*16<sup>1</sup> + 0*<sup>0</sup>

=1 * 256 + 0*16 + 0*1

= 256 + 0 + 0

=256