# Convert vector<bool> to binary

Tags: c++

I have a `vector<bool>` that contains 10 elements. How can I convert it to a binary type;

```
vector<bool> a={0,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,0}
```

I want to get binary values, something like this:

```
long long int x = convert2bin(s)
cout << "x = " << x << endl
```

x = 0b0111101110

Note: the size of vector will be change during run time, max size = 400.

`0b` is important, I want to use the gcc extension, or some literal type.

Comment: Could you use a `bitset`? It has a `to_ulong()` and `to_string()` method.

Comment: Thanks, I do not know the size of `a` during the compile time, can I use it?

Comment: @user1436187: No, but Boost has a resizable [`dynamic_bitset`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/dynamic_bitset/dynamic_bitset.html). There's no built-in conversion for `vector<bool>`, the best you can do is loop over the elements to build the value.

Comment: Are you going to have more then 32 or even more then 64 values in your vector?

Comment: Yes it can even hold 400 values. Later I want to convert it to hexa decimal.

Comment: So how do you imagine to put it into int?? You need some BigInt class for that.

Comment: So should I use `long long int`?

Comment: @user1436187 No, `long long int` can (usually) only hold 64 bits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understood of comment

> Yes it can even hold 400 values

And in question

> 0b is important

You need to have `string`, not `int`.

```
std::string convert2bin(const std::vector<bool>& v)
{
    std::string out("0b");
    out.reserve(v.size() + 2);
    for (bool b : v)
    {
        out += b ? '1' : '0';
    }  
    return i;
}
```

Comment: I want to do binary operation later, I put `0b` based on this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2611764/can-i-use-a-binary-literal-in-c-or-c

Comment: `0b` is just a compiler notion to interpret the following number as bin-formatted, it does not affect the underlying type, e.g. `int`. You can't expect the function to generate `0b something` and hope this will be some binary-literal-other-than-usual-int.

Comment: At least reserve space in the string.

Answer (score 1):

```
std::vector<bool> a = { 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0 };
std::string s = "";
for (bool b : a)
{
    s += std::to_string(b);
}
int result = std::stoi(s);
```

Comment: At least reserve space in the string.

Comment: Please add some context to your answer.

Answer (score 1):

If the number of bits is known in advance and by some reason you need to start from an std::array rather than from an std::bitset directly, consider this option ([inspired by this book](https://www.linuxtopia.org/online_books/programming_books/c++_practical_programming/c++_practical_programming_192.html)):

```
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <bitset>
#include <array>
#include <iterator>

/**
 * @brief Converts an array of bools to a bitset
 * @tparam nBits the size of the array
 * @param bits the array of bools
 * @return a bitset with size nBits
 * @see https://www.linuxtopia.org/online_books/programming_books/c++_practical_programming/c++_practical_programming_192.html
 */    
template <size_t nBits>
std::bitset<nBits> BitsToBitset(const std::array<bool, nBits> bits)
{
    std::ostringstream oss;
    std::copy(std::begin(bits), std::end(bits), std::ostream_iterator<bool>(oss, ""));
    return std::bitset<nBits>(oss.str());
}

int main()
{
    std::array<bool, 10> a = { 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0 };
    unsigned long int x = BitsToBitset(a).to_ulong();
    std::cout << x << std::endl;
    return x;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to do this, you start from the end. Although I support Marius Bancila and advise to use a bitset instead.

```
int mValue = 0
for(int i=a.size()-1, pos=0; i>=0; i--, pos++)
    {
        // Here we create the bitmask for this value
        if(a[i] == 1)
        {
            mask = 1;
            mask << pos;
            myValue |= mask;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can I assign a value to the `bitset` during run time?

Comment: Yes, you absolutely can. You cannot however modify the size of it without reinitalizing it. http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/bitset/bitset/

Comment: @LaszloFuleki: You can't modify the size at all. That's a compile-time constant.

Answer (score 0):

Your `x` is just an integer form from `a`, so can use `std::accumulate` like following

```
long long x = accumulate(a.begin(), a.end(), 0, 
                   [](long long p, long long q) 
                   { return (p << 1) + q; }
                  );
```

For a 400 size, you need a `std::string` though

Answer (score 0):

First of all the result of the conversion is not a literal. So you may not use prefix 0b applied to variable x.

Here is an example

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <algorithm>
#include <numeric>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>
#include <limits>

int main() 
{
    std::vector<bool> v = { 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0 };

    typedef std::vector<bool>::size_type size_type;
    size_type n = std::min<size_type>( v.size(), 
                                       std::numeric_limits<long long>::digits + 1 );

    long long x = std::accumulate( v.begin(), std::next( v.begin(), n ), 0ll,
                                   []( long long acc, int value )
                                   {
                                     return acc << 1 | value;
                                   } );

    for ( int i : v ) std::cout << i;
    std::cout << std::endl;

    std::cout << std::hex << x << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

The output is

```
0111101110
1ee
```

Answer (score 0):

`vector<bool>` is already a "binary" type.

Converting to an `int` is not possible for more bits than available in an `int`. However if you want to be able to print in that format, you can use a `facet` and attach it to the locale then `imbue()` before you print your `vector<bool>`. Ideally you will "store" the locale once.

I don't know the GNU extension for printing an `int` with `0b` prefix but you can get your print facet to do that.

A simpler way is to create a "wrapper" for your `vector<bool>` and print that.

Although `vector<bool>` is always internally implemented as a "bitset" there is no public method to extract the raw data out nor necessarily a standard representation for it.

You can of course convert it to a different type by iterating through it, although I guess you may have been looking for something else?