# Bit level operation

Tags: c

I am have been following a tutorial on bit level operation. the code that i was working on is as follows:

```
    int main(void){

    puts("bit-level calculations:");
    puts("----------------------");



    unsigned int x = 10;
    unsigned int y = 1;
    unsigned int result;


    result = x&y;
    printf("x & y = %d\n", result);

    result = x|y;
    printf("x | y = %d\n", result);

    result = x^y;
    printf("x ^ y = %d\n", result);



   }
```

the result was as follows:

x & y = 0

x | y = 11

x ^ y = 11

however my problem is with the first answer. what i understood is the 1 & 0 = 0, but 1& 1 = 1, what i was expecting was that i should have received an answer of 
at least 10 & 1 = 10. Because the first bit is 1 for the x and the first digit is 1 for the y. and the second bit for x is 0 and y bit is 0 so the result should be 0. the question is why did i get only zero where for the or and Xor i received two bits as a result.

thank you very much. i do understand that there are a few questions that was posted regarding the bit level operation, however the answer does not clarify my question.

Comment: You are confusing binary and decimal. `10` is decimal. In binary it is `1010`.

Comment: @Kaylum: In what world is binary 10 = decimal 1010? I think you might be the one that confused decimal and binary. :-) Decimal 10 = binary 1010, not the other way around.

Comment: @KenWhite Err, confusion reigns :-)  Thanks for pointing out my fat finger.

Comment: Here's a interactive tool: http://www.ambrsoft.com/MathCalc/BitP/bitPlay.htm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remember, these are **binary** operators. You've got to look at the numbers' base 2 bits, not their digits, which are base 10. Let's do that. I'll use subscripts to indicate what base each number is written in.

First, let's **convert the numbers to base 2**.

> 10<sub>10</sub> = 1010<sub>2</sub>     (ten in base 10 is "1010" in base 2)
>   1<sub>10</sub> = 1<sub>2</sub>             (in either base, one is written as "1")

Next, we must remember to work **right-to-left**, not left-to-right. We can do that by padding the numbers with 0's. Just as 37 is the same as 037 in decimal —both are thirty-seven—1<sub>2</sub> is the same as 0001<sub>2</sub> in binary.

> 10<sub>10</sub> = 1010<sub>2</sub>
>   01<sub>10</sub> = 0001<sub>2</sub>

Now perform the binary operations. Do you see now why 1010<sub>2</sub> & 0001<sub>2</sub> is equal to 0000<sub>2</sub>?

Comment: Thanks to all of you, i believe sg7 answer was right as well, however what i loved in John Kugelman answer is that it was more clear and step by step. as i said thanks to all of you guys i am quit sure you have all been so helpful. if only i had a choice to tick on all the answers i would have done so.

Answer (score 1):

Always consider radix when doing bitwise operations. It defaults to decimal in your program.

10<sub>10</sub> *and* 0xa *and* 012 *and* 0b1010 *and* 1010<sub>2</sub>, all are notations for the same thing.

That is, just as your decimal 10<sub>10</sub> is 1 * 10 + 0, it's also 1 * 2<sup>3</sup> + 2<sup>1</sup> or perhaps, mixing radices, 8 + 2, so in binary, 01010<sub>2</sub>.

When you combine it via operators with 1 (which, mercifully, is the same in every radix) you are matching up with the rightmost 0 in your 10<sub>10</sub>.

Answer (score 0):

Binary representation of 10 and 1 are as follows

10 = 1010

1 = 0001

So:

10 & 1

=
 1010 & 0001

=
0000

Answer (score 0):

In some versions of [`gcc` and other compilers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2611764/can-i-use-a-binary-literal-in-c-or-c), you can use literal binary values, i.e.

```
 unsigned int x = 0b10;  
 unsigned int y = 0b01;
```

Then it will work the way you want it to.