# How to split binary number into 6-bits binary numbers and add other bits in C?

Tags: c, binary, byte, bit

I am trying to split binary (for example `0100 0101 0100 0001`) into binaries with 6 bit size (get `0100`, `010101`, `000001`, ) and also add to them two binaries (add `10` to `000001` => `10000001`).

How can I do this in C?

Comment: Right shift as many times you need using `>>` then mask off the bits you don't want for each part with for example `& 0b111111`,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for [bitwise operators](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operations_in_C)

A few examples, with the mandatory `0b` at the beginning of binary literals:

```
0b0100010101000001 & 0b111111;// = 0b000001
0b0100010101000001 & (0b111111 << 6);// = 0b010101
0b0100010101000001 & (0b111111 << 12);// = 0b010001
0b101010 | (0b10 << 6);// = 0b10101010
```

Note: Depending on the compiler you are using, writing binary literals as `0bxxxx` may not be valid, as it is not standard. You may have to convert to decimal or hex (`0xAF`). See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2611764/can-i-use-a-binary-literal-in-c-or-c).

Answer (score 1):

You can use a combination of bit masks and bit shifts to extract portions of your source, and to modify the value after the extraction.

To isolate the *least significant* ('lowest') 6 bits from a source, mask that with binary 00111111 (hex 3F) using the [bitwise AND (`&`) operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/bitwise-and-operator-amp?view=msvc-170); to add the required "10" bits as the *most significant* ('highest') 2 bits, mask with binary 10000000 (hex 80) using the [bitwise (inclusive) OR (`|`) operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/bitwise-inclusive-or-operator-pipe?view=msvc-170).

For an *unsigned* source integer, you can perform the above operations sequentially, right-shifting by 6 bits (using the `>>` or `>>=` operator) after each extraction, until all required fields are extracted.

Taking your source as an `unsigned short` and your required destination as an array of 3 `unsigned char`, the following illustrates the process:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

void splitbyte(unsigned short src, unsigned char dst[3])
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i) {
        dst[i] = (src & 0x3F) | 0x80; // Extract the low 6 bits and mask in the top "10! bits
        src >>= 6;                    // Shift right by 6, so next loop extracts next field
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    unsigned short src = 0x4541; // 0100 0101 0100 0001
    unsigned char dst[3];
    splitbyte(src, dst);
    // You could printf in a loop but I wanted to comment each value ...
    printf("%02X\n", (unsigned)(dst[0])); // 81 = 10 000001
    printf("%02X\n", (unsigned)(dst[1])); // 95 = 10 010101
    printf("%02X\n", (unsigned)(dst[2])); // 84 = 10 000100
    return 0;
}
```