# Is directly putting in binary possible C++

Tags: c++, binary, byte

Is putting in binary as a value possible? I want something like `char test = 00101011` and it will become 43. I know this is possible by making a function that converts binary to decimal (which can be inputted)  but thats not direct and Im pretty sure it takes time.

Comment: Have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2611764/can-i-use-a-binary-literal-in-c-or-c).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to put the prefix `0b`.

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    char c = 0b00101011;
    std::cout << static_cast<int>(c) << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: `0b0010'1011` can also use the apostrophe as a number grouping, to make the long number sequences more legible.

Comment: @Eljay, that's optional.