# Visual studio c++ why don't 0b00000001 compile

Tags: c++, windows, binary, visual-studio-express

I am trying to port a small program I initially made for Linux, The only thing that gives me a error now is any binary numbers written like this `0b01010101`.

I can't find any information on why this does not work on windows or how I could get it to work on windows.

Is this not standard in c++?

Comment: No, it's not standard. It's a GCC extension.

Comment: It's part of C++14 and MSVC hasn't implemented that part yet. FWIW, Clang works on Windows and Linux and does have this feature implemented with `-std=c++1y`.

Comment: It will be a C++ feature in C++14.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/699781/c-binary-constant-literal for a way to use small binary constants in older compilers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Currently, this will not work.

This will be a new feature of [C++14](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C++14#Binary_literals). Numeric literals in C++14 can be specified in binary form. The syntax uses the prefixes `0b` or `0B`.

Comment: Visual C++ 2015 Preview supports C++14 binary literals: http://www.visualstudio.com/news/vs2015-preview-vs#C++