# value in array will be printed as 0 even after changing it in c

Tags: arrays, c

So I made a custom type by using `typedef unsigned char byte;`, and then declared an array of it, like using `byte mem[255];`. I used `mem[0] = 0x10100000;` to init the first value, but when I print it using `printf("%d", mem[0]);` I get `0`. Why?

Comment: `0x10100000` is a 32 bit value.  You probably meant `0xa0`

Comment: `0x10100000` is grossly over the storage capacity of an `unsigned char` You realize that's not a binary number, right? That's hexadecimal unsigned literal.

Comment: If your compiler is *very* new and supports the upcoming C23 standard (or have an extension that allows it) then you can use binary [integer constants](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/integer_constant) using the  `0b` prefix, as in `0b10100000`.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude and if you're not that lucky, you can use some template trickery to get there : [C++ binary constant/literal](https://stackoverflow.com/q/699781/5987).

Answer (score 2):

An `unsigned char` can typically only hold values between 0 and 255.  The hex value  0x10100000 is well out of range for that type, so (essentially) only the low-order byte of that value is used, which is 0.

Presumably you wanted to use a binary constant.  Not all compilers support that, but those that do would specify it as 0b10100000.  For those than don't you can use the hex value 0xA0.

Comment: yeah I should have done 'b' instead, but I got 'em mixed up

Answer (score 0):

You're assigning it the **hexidecimal** number `0x10100000` which is far larger than a single character, and thus can't be stored in a `byte`.  If you want to use a binary number, *and your compiler supports this*, you might try using `0b10100000` instead.

Answer (score 0):

`unsigned char` can only hold the value of `((1 << CHAR_BIT) - 1)`

You can check what is the maximum value yourself

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <limits.h>

int main(void)
{
    printf("%u\n", (1 << CHAR_BIT) - 1);
}
```

On most systems it is `255` or `0xff`.

When you assign the unsigned char with `0x10100000` only the lowest two hex digits will be assigned (in your case 0x00).

If you wanted to copy all the bytes from the `0x10100000` to the `byte` array `mem` you defined, the assignment will not work. You need to copy then instead:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef unsigned char byte;

int main(void)
{
    byte mem[100];

    memcpy(mem, &(unsigned){0x10100000}, sizeof(0x10100000));

    for(size_t index = 0; index < sizeof(0x10100000); index++)
    {
        printf("mem[%zu] = 0x%hhx\n", index, mem[index]);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
mem[0] = 0x0
mem[1] = 0x0
mem[2] = 0x10
mem[3] = 0x10
```

https://godbolt.org/z/cGYa8MTef

Why in this order? Because the machine, where godbolt is run, uses little endioan. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness

`0x` prefix means that number hexadecimal. If you wanted to use binary number then gcc supports `0b` prefix which is not standard.

`mem[0] = 0b10100000`

You can also create .h file

```
#define b00000000   0
#define b00000001   1
#define b00000010   2
#define b00000011   3

/* .... */
#define b11111110   254
#define b11111110   255
```

and use those definitions portable way

```
mem[0] = b10100000;
```

Comment: I accidentally used b instead of x and defined them wrongly

Answer (score -1):

You can't fit a 32 bit value inside an 8 bit variable (`mem[0]`). Do you perhaps mean to do this?

```
*(int *)mem = 0x10100000;
```

Comment: Seems unlikely.