# User-defined literals (Extended literals) of C++11... which compilers support it?

Tags: c++, metaprogramming, c++11, user-defined-literals

In [another thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/237804/user-defined-literals-in-c0x-a-much-needed-addition-or-making-c-even-more-bl/4051289#4051289) I introduced some techniques we would use for Model-Driven-Development in C++ once C++11 features, in particular user-defined literals, are available. I just revised the plans for GCC 4.5 and even 4.6 and it shows that this particular feature is not supported.

Anyway, do you know if I even have any compiler to test that feature to start designing/implementing the algorithms till the C++11 is approved and implemented in mainstream free compilers (LLVM, GCC)?

Comment: We (see bio) build a C++ front end used for reengineering purposes, and are C++0x as an upcoming standard that we are likely to implement sometime soon. While I understand what user defined literals *are*, I at least admit some puzzlement as to their motivating use case. Yet you seem have a specific use. Can you sketch why user defined literals are interesting, especially for a code generator which presumably can generate any code it likes, including arbitrary goo to initialize a struct? ... Why does a model driven guy even care?

Comment: Ira: nice question and you're right. For a code generator this feature is (almost) of little usage, apart from having to generate more classes or a less clean templates. *However* what we want to achieve is a very efficient embeeded DSL for specifying models, metamodels and model transformations in C++. By the help of metaprogramming, transformations can be much more efficient than by using, say, ATL under Java.

Comment: @Ira UDLs and const_expr should be usable to turn strings into hashcodes at compile time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not yet, although patches for both [Clang](http://lists.cs.uiuc.edu/pipermail/cfe-commits/Week-of-Mon-20100823/033943.html) and [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/ml/gcc/2010-09/msg00378.html) have been submitted and rejected for reworking, so you should see something soon.

Comment: Thanks! I was expecting at least any hints on how the process was being worked.

Answer (score 1):

None yet, as far as I know.

Answer (score 1):

GCC 4.7 (unreleased as of this posting) supports user-defined literals. For reference see http://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-4.7/changes.html and http://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-4.7/cxx0x_status.html .

Judging just from past GCC release [timelines](http://gcc.gnu.org/develop.html#timeline), I guess GCC 4.7 will be released sometime before May 2012.

You can use it right away if you want: I'm using a GCC 4.7 SVN snapshot right now specifically to play with user-defined literals and some other newly implemented C++11 features. They are working very well and I expect to use them in earnest when GCC 4.7 is released.

Comment: Thanks! That is good news. Thanks for letting me know. Let's see how I have time to play with it...