# How does C++ know anything between "quotation marks" is a std::string?

Tags: c++, string

This might be off-topic since there is no code, no output, no anything, but here goes.

The only way I see C++ can know `"this"` is a `std::string` is because the quotation mark is a language construct, much like the `char` between single quotes.
But I would be really surprised if it was the actual answer: does that imply `std::string` is the only way C++ has to interpret text between quotation marks? Then the standard lib would not be just an extension, but a part of C++.
What if I want to develop my own `MyString` class, and I want to create `MyStrings` on the fly using quotation marks: would I be able to do it or is the `""` syntax inevitably linked to the `std::string`?
I also thought about `""` being an operator (after all C++ has `operator()`), but I couldn't find anything about that.

Comment: `"this"` is a [*string literal*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/string_literal), it has nothing to do with `std::string`. You may define [your own string literals though](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/user_literal).

Comment: Perhaps you should look more into compiler theory and practice? Making a simple parser is actually not that hard, and would teach you a lot (including how to recognize constant string literals).

Comment: @VTT Bookmarked, thanks alot!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Let's clear up some misconceptions. The type of a string literal is a `const char[]`, *not* a `std::string`. For example, the type of `"this"` would be `const char[5]` (there is a null-terminator).

> does that imply `std::string` is the only way C++ has to interpret text between quotation marks?

No (it's not `std::string`) and there are multiple prefixes for utf-8 strings and wide character strings, like `L"wide"`.

> then the standard lib would not be just an extension, but a part of C++.

That's true, but not for string literals. You have the type of `nullptr` which is `std::nullptr_t`. There is also `std::byte` that gets special treatment by the standard. A `std::initializer_list` constructor is chosen when using list initialization. The result of `sizeof` is a `std::size_t` and of `typeid` it is a `std::type_info`. There may be others I can't think of right now.

> would I be able to do it or is the `""` syntax inevitably linked to the `std::string`?

It's not a `std::string`, but yeah, that's not possible. What you can do however is define a [user-defined literal](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/user_literal). `std::string` has one:

```
using namespace std::string_literals;
auto string = "this"s;

static_assert(std::is_same_v<decltype(string), std::string>); // ok
```

Comment: `std::initializer_list` is a big one too. A less visible one is `sizeof` returning `std::size_t`.

Comment: @Quentin Yes! `typeid` et al. is another one too! Thanks :D

Answer (score 3):

There are some good answers here, but none have addressed why the question comes up in the first place. Why would one think `"foo"` might have type `std::string`?

The answer is `std::string` has a constructor from `const char *` which will automatically turn the string literal into a `std::string` in many situations. C++ has ample mechanisms to allow making library and user defined data structures feel like part of the language in this way. (Operator overloading is another example.)

Consider that e.g. `strlen(std::string("foo"))` does not compile, so `"foo"` cannot be of type `std::string` directly.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying all of this! *"C++ has ample mechanisms to allow making library and user defined data structures feel like part of the language in this way."* -> **I totally agree**, that's why I'd have found it weird if quotation marks and `std::string` really were an inextensible language construct, hence my question.

Answer (score 1):

"this" is a string literal, not an `std::string`.

When you compile your code, [Parsing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parsing) takes action and goes through your code. When it meets enclosing double quotes, it assumes - by convention - that a string literal is found.

If you want to define your own string literals, then check [User-defined literals](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/user_literal) and [What new capabilities do user-defined literals add to C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/237804/what-new-capabilities-do-user-defined-literals-add-to-c)

<sub>PS: I suggest you take a Compiler's course, since if these issues excite you, you will love it.</sub>

Comment: Compiler courses look really fun, I'll sure get into it, thanks for the hint!