# What is the significance (or purpose) of this trailing s in this std::string_view example?

Tags: c++, c++17, string-view

**Update**: The answer(s) and discussion provided in the **[existing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/237804/what-new-capabilities-do-user-defined-literals-add-to-c)** answer are more than sufficient to satisfy this question.

If you have a similar question the suggested reading is this paper on [user-defined literals](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2007/n2378.pdf) and the [std::literals::string_literals::operator""s](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator%22%22s) reference

---

Reading through [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string_view) I came across this example. There is this trailing 's' at the end of the **bad** example and I am not sure what it signifies.

[image: cppreference]

Comment: User-defined literals.  Documentation on the specific example is here: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator%22%22s

Comment: The trailing `s` indicates that this should construct a `std::string`, which in this case is a temporary.  Since `string_view` is non-owning, it doesn't increase the temporary's lifespan

Comment: But all the overloads of ""s operator takes length also as parameter so how is this working : "a temporary string"s

Comment: @Kapil: `operator""s` is implicitly invoked by the literal expression. The compiler supplies the arguments. It knows them.

Comment: The link provided above by @StephenNewell was what I was initially looking for. The paper here http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2007/n2378.pdf is also a thorough explanation. Thanks!