# Std::Chrono 1s How can you place a number beside a string and expect C++ to understand?

Tags: c++, templates, c++-chrono

I see code using std::chrono that says things like:

auto tenSeconds = 10s;

I understand that Chrono defines a type s for seconds.  And I understand that the type of tenSeconds becomes something like chrono::second.  But isn't 10s just illegal C++?  Is there some operator I can redefine that allows me to place a number right beside a string and have C++ understand?

---

This question has been closed.  I am told that the answer is in another, previous question and answer.  [What new capabilities do user-defined literals add to C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/237804/what-new-capabilities-do-user-defined-literals-add-to-c)

I may just be dense, but I didn't understand until I looked in Stroustrup's book The C++ Programming Language.  I guess his explanation of what was trying to be accomplished, and his breaking out operator"" as a new kind of operator did it for me.

The previous answer referenced gave me enough clues to lead me back to Stroustrup, though.

Comment: Duplicate explains what's happening.

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/user_literal