# C++ - what does a _uv after a string mean?

Tags: c++

I came across modern c++ code for a Windows Driver using c++ classes that has:

```
static constexpr auto  FILESPEC { L"c:\\file.txt"_uv };
```

What does the `_uv` mean?

Comment: It's a user defined string literal. Since it's user defined I can't tell you what it means without seeing the definition. That will be an `operator ""_uv(const wchar_t*)` defined somewhere in the code you are looking at.

Comment: Incidentally I would hope that `"c:\file.txt"` in the code is actually `"c:\\file.txt"`

Comment: [What new capabilities do user-defined literals add to C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/237804/what-new-capabilities-do-user-defined-literals-add-to-c)

Comment: As a wild guess it's some magic to convert from UTF8 to windows UCS2 pathnames or something like that (that' `\f` seems suspicious tho... it's a form feed control character `0x0c`). As a suggestion just run (don't walk) away from that codebase if you can; the `static constexpr auto` thing is already a clear sign that it will suck terribly.

Comment: @6502 what's wrong with |static constexpr auto`?

Comment: @AlanBirtles it just shows a clear passion for overcomplicating things for no reason. As another wild guess for example that code contains `static_cast<T>(0)` instead of just `0` in a lot of places (because you can).

Comment: I had to add extra set of backslashes to get the double backslash to show.

Comment: Okay, thanks I found `constexpr ustring_view operator"" _uv(const wchar_t *str, std::size_t len) noexcept` which is part of building a UNICODE_STRING.  I'm not sure how it gets the length, there is a `ustring_view` constructor that takes a single parameter that gets the length.  Anyway, at least I know what it is.