# Using Protocol Buffers to send icons/small images

Tags: c++, stl, protocol-buffers

I have a simple question about std::string and google's protocol buffers library.
I have defined a message like so:

```
message Source
{
    required string Name = 1;
    required uint32 Id = 2;
    optional string ImplementationDLL = 3;
    optional bytes  Icon = 4;
}
```

I want to use the Icon field to send an image, it most probably will be a png image.
After feeding this to the protobuf compiler i got something like this to access/manipulate the Icon field.

```
inline bool has_icon() const;
inline void clear_icon();
static const int kIconFieldNumber = 4;
inline const ::std::string& icon() const;
inline void set_icon(const ::std::string& value);
inline void set_icon(const char* value);
inline void set_icon(const void* value, size_t size);
inline ::std::string* mutable_icon();
```

the std::string* mutable_icon() function is giving me a headache. It is returning a std::string but i believe strings can not hold binary data ! or can they ?

i can use set_icon(const void*, size_t) function to put binary data, but then how do i get it on the other side ?

i think std::string might be able to hold binary data, but how ????

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the answer to this question: [How do you construct a std::string with an embedded null?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/164168/how-do-you-construct-a-stdstring-with-an-embedded-null)

Answer (score 5):

```
const std::string s = icon();

const void *data=s.c_str();
```

Answer (score 4):

C++ strings represent the length explicitly, so [they can contain binary data](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4655232/28169), including the 0-character that terminates C strings.

You need to avoid passing the string to functions expecting a C-style string, since they won't handle embedded 0-chars.

Answer (score 1):

```
void String2Image(string binFile,const char* outImage)
{
    fstream imgFile(outImage,ios::binary|ios::out);

    for(int i=0; i<binFile.length(); ++i) 
    {
        imgFile << binFile[i];
    }

    imgFile.close();
}
```

Comment: That's pretty inefficient to write it out one byte at a time. Better to just write [`binFile.data()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/data/) in one go.