# Is it valid, to use std::string to hold binary data, to avoid manual dynamic memory management

Tags: c++

Pay attention to `base64_decode` in http://www.adp-gmbh.ch/cpp/common/base64.html

```
std::string base64_decode(std::string const& encoded_string)
```

The function is suppose to return `byte array` to indicate binary data. However, the function is returning `std::string`. My guess is that, the author is trying to avoid from perform explicit dynamic memory allocation.

I try to verify the output is correct.

```
int main()
{
    unsigned char data[3];
    data[0] = 0; data[1] = 1; data[2] = 2;
    std::string encoded_string = base64_encode(data, 3);
    // AAEC
    std::cout << encoded_string << std::endl;


    std::string decoded_string = base64_decode(encoded_string);
    for (int i = 0; i < decoded_string.length(); i++) {
        // 0, 1, 2
        std::cout << (int)decoded_string.data()[i] << ", ";
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
    getchar();
}
```

**The decoded output is correct. Just want to confirm, is it valid to `std::string` to hold binary data, to avoid manual dynamic memory management.**

```
std::string s;
s += (char)0;
// s.length() will return 1.
```

Answer (score 64, accepted):

Yes, you can store any sequence of `char` in a `std::string`. That includes any binary data.

Comment: And more specifically, that includes '\0' characters.

Comment: Of course, don't go around using `c_str()` in this case (well, don't expect the `\0` terminator to be an accurate indication of end-of-string anyway)

Comment: @bdonlan: You can user `c_str()` if you want to, but you probably need to consult `size()` as well. I prefer `data()` in this scenario, it feels more idiomatic. (`c_str()` and `data()` will do _exactly_ the same thing in C++0x.)

Comment: @CharlesBailey If string allows special char (including \0) then why does the below code print only 'Hello':
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
 string str = "Hello \0 World";
 cout << str << endl; 
 cout << str.data() << endl; 
    return 0;
}

Comment: @programmer: You should ask that as a new question. (Basically you've chosen a constructor that only reads to the first NUL for your string.)

Answer (score 20):

Yes. std::string can hold any char value (`'\0'` has no special meaning). However I wouldn't be surprised finding some C++ functions (e.g. from external libraries) having problems with strings with embedded NULs.

Anyway I don't understand what you are going to gain with an `std::string` instead of `std::vector<unsigned char>` that would make your intentions more clear and that offers more guarantees (e.g. that all the bytes are in contiguous not-shared memory so that you can pass `&x[0]` to someone expecting a plain buffer for direct access).

Comment: All bytes contiguous is not necessarily an advantage. Just a thought.

Comment: No. Is not me. The API is original designed by another author. Ask him! :)

Comment: @Charles : When dealing with byte/buffer, it is normal to assume the payload are contiguous.

Comment: In C++0X `std::string` is guaranteed to be contiguous, and all known implementations of C++03 are contiguous. See http://herbsutter.com/2008/04/07/cringe-not-vectors-are-guaranteed-to-be-contiguous/

Comment: @Charles Bailey: True, but in my experience buffer-type access is more common with binary data; also note that you can have no guarantee that a string implementation uses COW, so if you **need** that (e.g. for memory requirements) then you need to roll your own. With std::string you may or may not have COW (and Murphy says that you will get the opposite of what you need, especially if that for you is critical :-) )

Comment: @dalle: This is true, which makes my original point academic (even if valid).

Comment: @6502: If you're `std::string` implementation uses COW but it doesn't ensure a unique buffer when you retrieve a modifiable reference to a contained `char` then it is flawed in any case. My point was that if you have a very large string then chopping it into long subsequences can be kinder on your address space requirements. I wasn't really driving at COW / non-COW differences.

Comment: In C++0X `std::string` will probably not be allowed to utilize COW: http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2008/n2534.html

Comment: @dalle: I would not be suprised if they went without. There have been experiments that showed that COW was more of a hurdle in multi-threaded environments (because of the synchronization required).

Comment: FYI, Google also use the similar technique : http://code.google.com/apis/protocolbuffers/docs/proto.html#scalar

Comment: @6502: This is 'Sod's Law' not Murpheys. Murphey's Law: Everything that can go wrong will go wrong. Sod's Law: When things go wrong they will go wrong in the worst possible way.

Comment: If string allows special char (including \0) then why does the below code print only 'Hello':
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
 string str = "Hello \0 World";
 cout << str << endl; 
 cout << str.data() << endl; 
    return 0;
}

Comment: @programmer: For reasons that are not clear to me the standard `std::string` class only accepts a `const char *` for the constructor (not an array of char) and this means that the string literal `"Hello\0world"` will decay into a pointer before being used to build the string and the constructor will stop at the first `'\0'`. In other words while C++ strings have no problems containing `NUL` characters you cannot pass them using a string literal. I don't know why the standard didn't implement initialization from arrays (see http://stackoverflow.com/q/33751291/320726 )

Comment: @programmer: found the answer to why C++ doesn't handle initialization from string literals with embedded `NUL`s. String literals are arrays of chars that however include the ending `NUL`. Initializing a string from an array of chars without crazy special cases would need to include also that `NUL` and this is clearly not what would be useful. C++14 added a special `s` suffix that solves the problem (i.e. `std::string x = "Hello\0world."s;` builds a string with an embedded `NUL` but no extra `NUL` at the end).

Answer (score 2):

I don't think it's completely valid.
Care must be taken with string and binary data because it uses internally char type and char depends in the implementation if it is defined as unsigned or signed type. I prefer to use `basic_string<unsigned char>` and be sure of what i'm reading.

Answer (score 0):

I dont think one should use std::string for byte-data-storage. The method provide aren't design to deal with byte-data and you will risk yourself since any changes (or "optimization") on std::string will break your code.

Comment: Really? Can you provide a reference for this?

Answer (score 0):

it is better to use std::vector or std::vector  (where byte is typedef to uint8 ) to express nature of data. You will no longer have string specific functions available , which is what you want for binary data

Answer (score -6):

You need an array of character( not string)  to store the binary data.  Best is use vector.