# SWIG Python and C++ std::string null-termination problem

Tags: c++, python, string, swig

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How Python can get binary data(char*) from C++ by SWIG?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8163976/how-python-can-get-binary-datachar-from-c-by-swig)

I have a SWIG based C++ interface that can called from Python. There is a function in it, that has one std::string argument. It looks like this:

```
WrapperGet(const std::string& key);
```

If it is called from Python with a string argument that contains NUL character (e.g. binary data), then the std::string is truncated at the NUL character, and that is my problem, because it makes impossible to handle binary data.

What makes it interesting is that other way works perfectly:

```
std::string WrapperResult();
```

The string returned here can contain binary data without truncation. Has anybody any idea what has to be done?

UPDATE: I debugged the SWIG generated code and it turned out that the error was in the wrapper code on the C++ size: it used the c_str() member function of the std::string to get the string value.

Thanks for everybody's ideas and time!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/164168/how-do-you-construct-a-stdstring-with-an-embedded-null

Comment: The problem is not with std::string, but SWIG _with_ std::string. Do you have how to compile SWIG to achieve this?

Comment: Isn't the problem that he shouldn't be using std::string to represent NUL data. I don't know anything about SWIG but if you construct the string by passing a character array, you will get the problem you are seeing. Maybe a vector<unsigned char> would work better.

Comment: @Lou, a vector<char> _would_ work better, but technically std::string should be able to handle nulls for the most part. This sounds like a SWIG issue.

Comment: @Lou: `std::string` can handle NUL characters perfectly, if instead of passing only a pointer into a char array you pass also the size, it will read the whole contents regardless of possible internal NULs. The constructor you mentioned is just provided for compatibility with C strings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've had to deal with this in the past, and I just grabbed the `std::string` conversion template from SWIG and tailored it a bit to use `PyString_FromStringAndSize` when creating a Python string from a `std::string` and the `std::string` constructor that accepts a size argument when going the other way.

That was with a really old version of SWIG, though - I thought the builtin conversion template in newer versions had been updated to do that automatically. Is it possible the problem is on the C++ side? (e.g. as in Mark Tolonen's examples, where the first example is truncated due to the embedded NULL in the constructor call without a size argument).

Answer (score 1):

It is probably how the strings are constructed.  Consider:

```
string blah(const string& x)
{
    string y("abc\x00def");
    return x + y;
}

string blah2(const string& x)
{
    string y("abc\x00def",7);
    return x + y;
}
```

Calling these from Python:

```
>>> import x
>>> x.blah('abc\x00def')
'abc\x00defabc'
>>> x.blah2('abc\x00def')
'abc\x00defabc\x00xyz'
```

The constructor for `std::string(const char*)` stops at the NULL, but clearly SWIG can pass in and return strings with a NULL in them.