# How Python can get binary data(char*) from C++ by SWIG?

Tags: c++, python, char, swig

I am using C++ functions in Python by SWIG,and I met a problem now.
When I pass a char * from C++ to Python, the char * is truncted by Python.

For example:

example.h:

```
char * fun()
{
    return "abc\0de";
}
```

now in Python,we call 
    example.fun()
it only print 
    "abc" 
instead of 
    "abc\0de"
the data behind '\0' is deleted by Python.

I want to get all the chars(it is a binary data that can contains '\0') from fun() in C++,
and any advise is appreciated

Comment: The reverse situation (passing binary data **to** C/C++) is well covered by the docs. (Your question is not so well covered AFAIK). http://www.swig.org/Doc3.0/Library.html#Library_nn10

Answer (score 6, accepted):

C/C++ strings are NULL-terminated which means that the first `\0` character denotes the end of the string.

When a function returns a pointer to such a string, the caller (SWIG in this case) has no way of knowing if there is more data after the first `\0` so that's why you only get the first part.

So first thing to do is to change your C function to return not just the string but its length as well. Since there can be only one return value we'll use pointer arguments instead.

```
void fun(char** s, int *sz)
{
    *s = "abc\0de";
    *sz = 6;
}
```

The SWIG docs suggest using the `cstring.i` [library](http://www.swig.org/Doc1.3/Library.html#Library_nn12) to wrap such functions. In particullar, the last macro does exactly what you need.

```
%cstring_output_allocate_size(parm, szparm, release)
```

Read [the docs](http://www.swig.org/Doc1.3/Library.html#Library_nn12) to learn how to use it.

Comment: Sorry for my poor English(haha,I am a Chinese), and you help me solve the problem that confused me for about one whole week. thank you very much ~~~

Answer (score 8):

First of all, you should not use `char *` if you are dealing with binary data (swig thinks that they are normal strings). Instead you should use `void *`. swig provides a module named 'cdata.i' -
you should include this in the interface definition file.

Once you include this, it gives two functions - `cdata()` and `memmove()`.

- Given a `void *` and the length of the binary data, `cdata()` converts it into a string type of the target language.
- `memmove()` does the reverse - given a string type, it will copy the contents of the string(including embedded null bytes) into the C `void*` type.

Handling binary data becomes much simpler with this module. I hope this is what you need.

```
example.i
%module example
%include "cdata.i"
%{
void *fun()
{
        return "abc\0de";
}
%}

test.py
import example
print example.cdata(example.fun(), 6)
```

Comment: Could you also give an example on how to use `memmove()`?

Answer (score 0):

See [8.3 C String Handling](http://www.swig.org/Doc1.3/Library.html#Library_nn8) in the documentation.

Also from the [documentation](http://www.swig.org/Doc1.3/SWIG.html#SWIG_nn10):

> The char * datatype is handled as a NULL-terminated ASCII string. SWIG
>   maps this into a 8-bit character string in the target scripting
>   language. SWIG converts character strings in the target language to
>   NULL terminated strings before passing them into C/C++. The default
>   handling of these strings does not allow them to have embedded NULL
>   bytes. Therefore, the char * datatype is not generally suitable for
>   passing binary data. However, it is possible to change this behavior
>   by defining a SWIG typemap. See the chapter on Typemaps for details
>   about this.