# How to assign char* (with every possible value) to C++ string

Tags: c++, string, char

I'm in C++. And I'm trying to append a char array to a C++ string. The only thing is that this array can have every possible value, negative, positive and 0. So when I assign this array to the string, it stops at some point because it found a 0 value.
1) Can string append these values? Or do they have to be strictly from 1 to 127?
If true,
2) Is there a way to keep the string assignment going even even if it finds a 0?

Comment: Why use a `std::string` in the first place? A `vector` would be better suited.

Comment: String has comparison functions. I need that. Even though if compares the -125 value character to the 5 value character. -125 should be less than 5.

Comment: Michael Burr's answer should do what you want, but I'm curious to know how you're currently trying to do this (to work out why it's stopping at `\0` for you). Also in answer to your first question, a std::string can contain (I believe) any character, including `\0`.

Comment: You can also use features from `<algorithm>` on `vector` if needed.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you construct a std::string with an embedded null?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/164168/how-do-you-construct-a-stdstring-with-an-embedded-null)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `string::append( const char* s, size_t n )` overload for `append()` should do what you want.  Assuming that `cpp_string` is your `std::string` variable or reference and `c_string_ptr` is your pointer to an array of characters:

```
cpp_string.append( c_string_ptr, number_of_bytes);
```

Note however, the `std::string` is a typedef for `std::basic_string<char>`. Since `char` might not be signed on your platform you might not get the comparison behavior you want.  You should ensure that `char` is signed on your platform or you might want to use your own typedef to prevent problems if the platform (or build) changes in the future:

```
typedef std::basic_string<signed char> sstring;  // or whatever name you like
```

Answer (score 2):

Use **[string::append()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/append/)** function.

Code Example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main ()
{
  string str2="My String";

  str.append("is nice",7);

  cout << str << endl;
  return 0;
}
```

*Is there a way to keep the string assignment going even even if it finds a 0?*
character arrays are null terminated, and use 0 to determine the end of array.
std::string does not use 0 to determine end of string.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following functions:

> string& append ( const char* s, size_t n );
>
> string& append ( const char* s );

The first one will append with the char* until it reach the size, the second will append until it found a `\0` int the string.

So you can use the first with any value of chars, but you have to take care with the second since (char)0 will terminates the appending.

See: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/append/