# I need copyable buffer, as light as possible (e.g. not zero initialized)?

Tags: c++, stl, buffer

I need raw buffers of very big size (let say more MB than KB) as light as possible. I would like to have it keep the data in dynamic area, not necessarily it shall be grow-able, I will set the size at construction.

I thought about `std::vector<unsigned char>` but:

```
std::vector<unsigned char>  a(VERY_BIG_SIZE);
```

has the data initialized to `0` - I don't need this, I don't want to pay for it... This is embedded system already of high usage of CPU/RAM and I want to benefit from the fact that memory allocated but not used is only virtually allocated (I mean it takes some address space but it is not mapped to real memory unless used).

I thought also about:

```
std::vector<unsigned char> a;
a.reserve(VERY_BIG_SIZE);
std::copy(someData..., a.begin());
```

it surprisingly works as expected (I guess this UB somehow) - and the `a` whole memory is not initialized, but as you already noticed, I cannot copy `a` to other vector because `(a.begin()== a.end())`....

---

I need to explain somehow why I did not do `push_back(...)/insert(a.end(), ...)/assign(...)` in my second approach.

I already have template class Buffer with constant size:

```
template <size_t SIZE>
class Buffer {
public: 
// this "dirty" solution works, but I would need to add copy stuff by myself...
  Buffer()  { data.reserve(SIZE); }
// this "correct" solution is too heavy:
  Buffer() : data(SIZE) { }

  unsigned char* data() const { return &data[0]; }
private:
  std::vector<unsigned char> data;
  // unsigned char data[SIZE]; // this is not an option because it is not dynamic memory
};
```

Is there anything I can put in private part of `Buffer` that will take care of memory management and it will be copyable and not initialized... And memory would be dynamically allocated (like std::Vector does) that is why `unsigned char data[SIZE];` is not an option.

Any ideas?

Comment: What sense does it make to dynamically allocate memory when the size is known at compile time? In your case a quick call to `malloc` might be the best solution.

Comment: @pmr In my system I can afford to allocated big buffer in heap, but not in stack. Buffer objects are on stack - but their working memory shall not be on stack (stack is of too little size - and I say I want to have unused part of buffer only in virtual memory not in the real memory)...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Std vector of a struct that is packed to 1 byte and whose default constructor leaves then contents uninitialized (ie does nothing) should work.

Note that you can do mass inserts into an empty vector, and the only initialization will be from the incoming data.  Ie, `vect.insert( vect.end(), random_access_iterator_begin, blah_end )` might have the performance you want.

Comment: I never understood why anyone would use that ugly `insert` construct if there is `vector::assign`.

Comment: Vector may not be empty.  I did not want to presume!  More specifically, if be is throwing data in chunks at the vector, chain range insert keeps the bounds checks minimal.

Comment: Such type "1 byte struct with empty defined default constructor` is not POD type - so std::vector::vector(size_t n)` will call this constructor N times. Do you think it will be optimized away somehow?

Comment: see update to my question. I was too fast with posting the question - it did not contain the most relevant part... Your solution looks pretty OK - but can I be sure that this empty constructor won't be called?

Comment: You can check, but yes I expect a side effect free loop to optimize to nothing.

Comment: Of course I will check, still afraid that even if it works now, it can stop when we upgrade compiler or library...

Comment: If it makes you feel better note that a `struct {}` has size 1.  But that seems overkill to me.

Comment: I will try with `struct {}` too. When I have results I will add it to my question. Another thing I must check is the cost of copying the vector. Since your type is not POD (it has constructor) in C++03 (I use gcc4.4) then I am afraid it will be copied one by one, not with `memcpy`. In C++11 your type is trivially copyable - so it is a chance that in future it would work as wished.

Comment: Ah good point, `struct {}` may not copy.  In my experience loops of  St copies can be as fast as memcpy.  If you think about it there is no reason for it to be slower, except your presumption that memcpy 'should' be faster.  I wonder if union could be useful?  Probably not.

Comment: @Yakk The only reason `memcpy` can be faster is that it is coded to take advantage, *at runtime*, of machine word alignment and size, usually using an SSE2-enhanced instruction set on x86-64 by default.

Answer (score 2):

You are almost on the right track with `vector::reserve`.

I recommend using reserve in combination with `vector::assign` and `vector::push_back`. That does exactly what you want.

```
std::vector<unsigned char> a;
a.reserve(VERY_BIG); // check capacity to see how much memory was reserved
std::copy(someData.begin(), someData.end(), 
          std::back_inserter(a)); // allocation free copy
// or
a.assign(someData.begin(), someData.end());
```

After your update, I'd implement my own buffer.

```
template<std::size_t Size>
class buffer {
public:
  buffer() : b_(new unsigned char[Size]) {}
  buffer(const buffer& other) {
    std::copy(other.begin(), other.end(), this->begin());
  }
  buffer& operator=(const buffer& other) { 
    // intentionally no protection against self assignment
    std::copy(other.begin(), other.end(), this->begin());
    return *this;
  }
  ~buffer() { delete [] b_; }
  // move operations, if desired

  unsigned char* begin() { return b_; }
  unsigned char* end() { return b_ + Size; }
  // const versions...

private:
  unsigned char* b_;
};
```

This should have all your desired characteristics (heap allocated,
deep copyable, uninitialized on creation).

Comment: One problem is that back inserter cannot know how much is to come.  It makes it harder for the optimizer to remove the bounds checks and reduce them to once per mass insert, I suspect.  Maybe the compiler will impress me however!

Comment: This is solution is OK with my question (+1), but: see update to my question. I was too fast with posting the question - it did not contain the most relevant part...

Comment: @PiotrNycz I added a solution that should do mostly what you need.

Comment: Yes, I thought about doing the task in this way, but only if I did not find anything else... Drawbacks in comparing to `std::vector`are: 1) need to create detailed unit tests 2) hand work is an subject to followers (team work) to screw it up 3) Now "move stuff" is not possible in gcc4.4 - but in next upgrade I shall remember that I need to add move constructor to it - `std::vector` will do it for me....

Comment: @PiotrNycz With some compiler feature detection macros (Boost.Config) you can already write the move code now and even test it. For the rest: special requirements require special code :)

Answer (score 1):

All of the standard containers initialize all the memory asked for. Using a `std::vector<unsigned char>` with reserved memory seems to be the option, though: You can always add elements using

```
std::vector<unsigned char> a;
a.reserve(VERY_BIG_SIZE);
a.insert(a.end(), new_data.begin(), new_data.end());
```

Puts the data directly into the appropriate location without extra initialization. Of course, this means that the data you actually did store in your container is contiguous at the start of the container. If you need to access random positions in your big buffer and want to be able to only copy the corresponding sections things become a lot more involved and there isn't anything in the standard C++ library readily doing this.

BTW, since you linked to this question from an approach using a stream buffer to write data into an area: it would be possible to combine the approach but it would be more involved than using the vector's storage as the stream's output buffer: Since you'd need to track the size of the vector you'd need to make the available buffer empty, having it incremented for each character. This would technically work but would be slow. Instead, you'd give the stream buffer a buffer and transfer it to the end of your `std::vector<unsigned char>` upon `overflow()` or when `pubsync()`ing the stream buffer (which is what `std::flush` triggers).

Comment: See update to my question. I was too fast with posting the question - it did not contain the most relevant part...

Comment: Your answer is not very optimistic ;) Yakk's solution looks very promising - what do you think about `struct UnitializedByte { char c; UnitializedByte(){/*empty*/}}; std::vector<UnitializedByte> a(VERY_BIG_SIZE);` I'm afraid about CPU load - will `VERY_BIG_SIZE*callling UnitializedByte empty constructor` be optimized away just because c-tor is empty?

Comment: The main question I'd have with respect to what copy is supposed to do still stands: When you copy your buffer is it meant to read the entire buffer or somehow only parts of it? I don't think there is any readily available container really helping with what you seem to want but creating a suitable class seems close to trivial - once you worked out what it actually needs to do!

Comment: Even if the constructor doesn't do anything, the system will move through the memory. It may remove most of the operations, though. The value type is a bit awkward to use, though, e.g., because it doesn't create a zero value when default constructing it. In C++ 2003 it doesn't help you any, of course, because you want the copy to work and there is only one value default constructed and all other elements are copied from this object. I'd consider this approach to fragile.

Comment: I want to copy everything (copying is very rare, almost unlikely to happen - but it shall be possible). Yes, doing it myself is an option - just it costs not only these few lines of copy stuff - but I would need to remember to add move stuff when we move from gcc4.4 to gcc4.5 and would need to add unit testing, prepare some docs how it works and how it is implemented to team and register this as potential memory leak source in our code database. With something from std library I would not need to do most of it. You know - real programming is not so fun...

Comment: Good point with copying - it will cost too much in gcc4.4 - it is not POD - so something as light as `memcpy` couldn't be used, every element will be copied one by one. In C++11 it will be detected that type is trivially copyable and it will be copied like array of unsigned char.  Do I understand your point correctly?

Comment: Well, I'm working in a profession environment and I realize the benefit of using a component from somewhere else. However, the tests for this stuff won't be too bad, nor the documentation ("except for initialization behaves like `std::vector<unsigned char>`; see `std::vector`).
With respect to the difference to C++ 2011 is that in C++ 2011 the vector members are default constructed, not copy constructed. Of course, for well-behaved value types it doesn't make a difference but if your default constructor does something funny it may be all the difference...

Answer (score 0):

You could always do `unsigned char *a = new unsigned char[n];`.

Comment: Such `a` is not deep copyable. I would need to implement copy stuff by myself. I will prefer solution with as little effort from my side as possible...

Comment: What does it mean for an uninitialized array of bytes to be deep copied? Are all bytes read or are only some of them read?

Comment: I have occasionally seen need for a value_semantics_ptr smart pointer, that does deep copy on =, and can be taught to call clone functions or methods.  Such would be useful here.