# Are basic_string literals faster or handled better at compile-time?

Tags: c++, string, literals, c++14, user-defined-literals

While skimming over the draft of C++14/C++1y (n3690) I noticed the introduction of the **`basic_string` litertal suffixes** in section §21.7:

```
inline namespace literals {
inline namespace string_literals {
  // 21.7, suffix for basic_string literals:
  string operator "" s(const char *str, size_t len);
  u16string operator "" s(const char16_t *str, size_t len);
  u32string operator "" s(const char32_t *str, size_t len);
  wstring operator "" s(const wchar_t *str, size_t len);
}
}
```

My questions are:

- Is there a possibility to be faster at run-time with `basic_string` literals?
- Is my "naive" implementation totally wrong?
- Can the layout of data in ROM be different with `basic_string` literals, or any other difference at compile-time versus run-time?

## Background

I know that this allows the direct use of string literals like this:

```
std::string s1 = "A fabulous string"s;

void sfunc(std::string arg);

int main() {
    sfunc("argument"s);
}
```

**But what is the advantage of that over relying on the *conversion constructor* `string(const char*)`?**

The "old" code would look:

```
std::string s1 = "A fabulous string";  // c'tor string(const char*)

void sfunc(std::string arg);

int main() {
    sfunc("argument");   // auto-conversion via same c'tor
}
```

As far as I can see the implementation of `operator "" s()` would basically look like this:

```
std::string operator "" s(const char* lit, size_t sz) {
    return std::string(lit, sz);
}
```

So, just the use of the same c'tor. And my guess is, that has to be done at run-time, am I wrong?

**Edit:** As *Nicol Bolas* pointed out correctly below my example does *not* use the same constructor, but the one with the additional length -- which is very useful for the construction, obviously. This leaves with me the question: Is this better for the compiler to putting string literals into ROM, or something similar at compile-time?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> - Is there a possibility to be faster at run-time with basic_string literals?

As already stated, the string length is known and automatically passed to the constructor.

> - Is my "naive" implementation totally wrong?

No, it's correct.

> - Can the layout of data in ROM be different with basic_string literals, or any other difference at compile-time versus run-time?

Probably not, because the relevant `basic_string` constructor is not `constexpr` so won't be eligible for static initialization, so probably can't be put in ROM and has to be done at run-time.

Answer (score 5):

> So, just the use of the same c'tor.

OK, let's see how that would look:

```
string fromLit = "A fabulous string"s;
string fromBare = string("A fabulous string");
```

See anything missing in `fromBare`? Let me spell it out for you:

```
string fromBare = string("A fabulous string"/*, NOTHING*/);
```

Yeah, you can't get the *length* of the string without... getting it's length. Which means that `fromBare` will have to iterate through the literal to find the `\0` character. At runtime. `fromLit` will not; the compiler provides the string's length as a compile-time determined parameter. Any compiler worth using will just bake the length into the executable code.

And even if that *wasn't* the case, it's still better for other reasons. Consider this:

```
void SomeFunc(const std::string &);
void SomeFunc(const char *);

SomeFunc("Literal");
SomeFunc("Literal"s);
SomeFunc(std::string("Literal"));
```

The last two do the same thing (minus the point I made before), but one of them is *much* shorter. Even if you employ `using std::string` (or foolishly `using namespace std;`), the second one is still shorter. Yet it's clear exactly what's going on.

Comment: Very good point! Having the length is an advantage, sure enough.

Comment: With regards to performance, I doubt that string literals will give a boost to using a static const: `static std::string lit( "Literal" );`; they may even be significantly slower.  Having to invent a name and declare an extra variable is a pain, however, and string literals are definitly an improvement on those grounds.

Answer (score 1):

It provides more compile-time safety.

Consider [How do you construct a std::string with an embedded null?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/164168/how-do-you-construct-a-stdstring-with-an-embedded-null/12884464#12884464)

The only way to construct a `std::string` from a string literal that contains a null character is to either specify the size of the string literal (error prone), use `initializer_list` syntax (verbose) or to do some sort of loop with multiple calls to `push_back` (even more verbose). However, with the literal constructor, the size is automatically passed in for you, removing a possible source of error.

Comment: Interesting point, but quite rare. String Literals containing `\0` -- happens, but seldomly. And since the author has control over string literals he introduces only a small issue. +1 nonethelesse, for the interesting aspect.