# How to copy a string with multiple null characters to a stringstream?

Tags: c++, stringstream

I have an example string:

> test1\0test2\0test3\0

And I want to be able to copy it to a stringstream. I've tried the following methods which are not working:

```
sStream << teststring;
sStream.write(teststring, 99);
```

Is there a simple way to copy text to a stringstream while ignoring null characters?

Comment: What is the output you get with that example?

Comment: The output I am getting is "test1". Everything beyond the first null is left out.

Comment: [Works fine for me](http://ideone.com/t0EOQU).

Comment: I'm actually reading the string from a socket. I get the correct number of bytes read, but when I try to add the buffer to the stringstream I only get the first section.

Comment: I am trying to write the string to the stringstream. It starts as a char array in a socket buffer, so std::string is not being used. Here is an example of what I am seeing: [example](http://ideone.com/Lb35vf)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you using **[`std::string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string)** like [**Kerrek SB**](https://stackoverflow.com/users/596781/kerrek-sb)? It becomes as simple as the following:

```
int main()
{
    std::ostringstream ss;
    std::string testString("a\0b\0c\0d", 7);

    ss.write(&testString[0], testString.size());

    std::cout << ss.str(); // abcd
}
```

Comment: This pretty much did it. I had tried using std::string before, but I was missing the difference made by using the constructor with two arguments. [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/164168/how-do-you-construct-a-stdstring-with-an-embedded-null) helped out too.