# How to assign data inside a char pointer in C++ to JSONCPP

Tags: c++, arrays, json, char

I have a big character array. Lets say it contains 4500 bytes.

**Case #1:**

If I write the following code the complete value is not displayed

```
cout << filecontent << endl;
```

**Case #2:**

In this case, it is working perfectly fine.

```
for(int i=0; i <= size; i++) 
            cout << filecontent[i];
```

My issue is I want to assign the value to `Json::Value`. If I do normal assignment operation, it takes only the garbage value.

**Why it is so?**

As far as my understanding, whenever the actual data contains `\0` it treats as the end of the value.

How to overcome this issue?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you construct a std::string with an embedded null?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/164168/how-do-you-construct-a-stdstring-with-an-embedded-null)

Comment: @IvayloStrandjev when I try with `string actualcontent(filecontent, size);` and trying with actualcontent also not giving me the proper value?

Comment: Assuming OP is referring to http://jsoncpp.sourceforge.net/ then the std::string constructor copies the string to a char*, and throws away the length (I think), so will stop at the first Null.

Comment: jsoncpp doesn't treat NULL as a control character, instead just using it to terminate strings.

Comment: I guess OP will need to find a different Json library.

Comment: I checked the program again. Once it copies to `std::string` that time itself the issue started. Nothing to do with JSONCPP.

Comment: But even once you get a std::string with an embedded NULL, it won't help you since JSONCPP only deals with char* so will stop at the first  NULL as far as I can see.

Comment: This is a bug in `jsoncpp`, since zero is valid UTF8. [Here is a ticket](https://github.com/open-source-parsers/jsoncpp/issues/176).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create std::string with NULLs in by passing in an explicit length.

This doesn't help you if you are using [JsonCPP](http://jsoncpp.sourceforge.net), since that stores `char*` internally, even if you pass in a `std::string`, so loses the length and terminates at the first NULL. Also it doesn't have handling for NULL as a control character so would just put NULL (rather than \u0000) into the JSON.

I think you will need to find a different JSON library to do what you want. The only other alternative I've thought of is to generate template JSON with a stand-in for your data, then do your own replacement and escaping after generation. Of course alternatively you could fix the problem and submit a patch if you wanted.

Answer (score 0):

use write. as in:

```
cout.write( filecontent, size );
```

if you need a string, use a stringstream:

```
stringstream strstr;
strstr.write( filecontent, size );
string ss = strstr.str();
```

requires header `<sstream>`

Comment: How to assign it to other variable, especially `Json::Value` ?

Comment: @Prabhu `std::copy`throws the `error C2039: 'iterator_category' : is not a member of 'std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Ax>'`

Comment: try string::copy instead of std::copy? There is always a crude way to get anything working. Resize Json::Value and do a memcpy :)...