# GetUserPreferredUILanguages() never returns more than two languages

Tags: windows, winapi, internationalization, translation, multilingual

I'm trying to retrieve the complete list of the user's preferred languages from a C++/Qt application, as configured in the "Region & language" page in the user's preferences:

[image: Preferred languages]

For that, I am trying with the WinAPI function [GetUserPreferredUILanguages()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winnls/nf-winnls-getuserpreferreduilanguages), on an up-to-date Windows 10 Pro system.

However, the function always only returns the first entry (the main Windows display language), and "en-US". If English is configured as the main language, then only "en-US" is returned. E.g., if I have (German, French, English) configured, ["de-de", "en-US"] is returned, French is omitted. If I add more languages to the list, they are omitted as well.
I also looked at [User Interface Language Management](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/desktop/Intl/user-interface-language-management), but to no avail. GetSystemPreferredUILanguages() for example only returns "en-US". [GetUILanguageFallbackList()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/Muiload/nf-muiload-getuilanguagefallbacklist) returns ["de-de", "de", "en-US", "en"].

The code I use:

```
// calling GetUserPreferredUILanguages() twice, once to get number of 
// languages and required buffer size, then to get the actual data

ULONG numberOfLanguages = 0;
DWORD bufferLength = 0;
const auto result1 = GetUserPreferredUILanguages(MUI_LANGUAGE_NAME,
                                                 &numberOfLanguages,
                                                 nullptr,
                                                 &bufferLength);
// result1 is true, numberOfLanguages=2

QVector<wchar_t> languagesBuffer(static_cast<int>(bufferLength));
const auto result2 = GetUserPreferredUILanguages(MUI_LANGUAGE_NAME,
                                                 &numberOfLanguages,
                                                 languagesBuffer.data(),
                                                 &bufferLength);

// result2 is true, languageBuffer contains "de-de", "en-US"
```

Is this not the right function to use, or am I misunderstanding something about the language configuration in Windows 10? How can I get the complete list of preferred languages? I see [UWP API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.system.userprofile.globalizationpreferences.languages) that might do the job, but if possible, I'd like to use C API, as it integrated more easily with the C++ codebase at hand. (unmanaged C++, that is)

Comment: That's strange. On my computer this returns only 1 language, even though I have installed other languages for testing.

Comment: It would appear that the language codes are separated by nulls `'\0'.` `floor(bufferLength / 4)` should equate to `numberOfLanguages`.

"...this function retrieves an ordered, null-delimited user preferred UI languages list,... This list ends with two null characters"

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winnls/nf-winnls-getuserpreferreduilanguages

If the null char is seen as the end of the buffer, for example in std::string constructor.. I assume this is why I only see the first 4 chars of the buffer in the Visual Studio text visualizer.

Comment: Similar/related question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42874699/stdstring-stops-at-0

Comment: see `std::string languages(languagesBuffer.data(), bufferLength)`
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/string/

Comment: @mynameisnafe that wasn't the problem, i split the data at the null bytes, being aware that is not a single string. Also note that i got two entries, not one.

Comment: @FrankOsterfeld indeed, your string looks good. It might be worth looking at the MUI_ flags as there is a licencing aspect to installed languages in Windows, so if you've installed 'unlicenced' ones, they might not be in the list by default?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`GlobalizationPreferences.Languages` is usable from unmanaged C++ because `GlobalizationPreferences` has [`DualApiPartitionAttribute`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.foundation.metadata.dualapipartitionattribute).
Here is a C++/WinRT example  of using `GlobalizationPreferences.Languages`:

```
#pragma once
#include <winrt/Windows.Foundation.Collections.h>
#include <winrt/Windows.System.UserProfile.h>
#include <iostream>
#pragma comment(lib, "windowsapp")

using namespace winrt;
using namespace Windows::Foundation;
using namespace Windows::System::UserProfile;

int main()
{
    winrt::init_apartment();

    for (const auto& lang : GlobalizationPreferences::Languages()) {
        std::wcout << lang.c_str() << std::endl;
    }
}
```

And a WRL example for those who cannot migrate to C++ 17:

```
#include <roapi.h>
#include <wrl.h>
#include <Windows.System.UserProfile.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdint.h>
#pragma comment(lib, "runtimeobject.lib")

using namespace Microsoft::WRL;
using namespace Microsoft::WRL::Wrappers;
using namespace ABI::Windows::Foundation::Collections;
using namespace ABI::Windows::System::UserProfile;

int main()
{
    RoInitializeWrapper initialize(RO_INIT_MULTITHREADED);
    if (FAILED(initialize)) {
        std::cerr << "RoInitialize failed" << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }

    ComPtr<IGlobalizationPreferencesStatics> gps;
    HRESULT hr = RoGetActivationFactory(
        HStringReference(
            RuntimeClass_Windows_System_UserProfile_GlobalizationPreferences)
            .Get(),
        IID_PPV_ARGS(&gps));
    if (FAILED(hr)) {
        std::cerr << "RoGetActivationFactory failed" << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }

    ComPtr<IVectorView<HSTRING>> langs;
    hr = gps->get_Languages(&langs);
    if (FAILED(hr)) {
        std::cerr << "Could not get Languages" << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }

    uint32_t size;
    hr = langs->get_Size(&size);
    if (FAILED(hr)) {
        std::cerr << "Could not get Size" << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }
    for (uint32_t i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
        HString lang;
        hr = langs->GetAt(i, lang.GetAddressOf());
        if (FAILED(hr)) {
            std::cerr << "Could not get Languages[" << i << "]" << std::endl;
            continue;
        }
        std::wcout << lang.GetRawBuffer(nullptr) << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! That works perfectly (using MSVC 2019 and C++17). Notes to Qt/QMake users: Make sure to enable C++17 (`CONFIG+=c++17`), link windowsapp.dll (`LIBS += -lwindowsapp`). Do not call `winrt::init_apartment();` (I guess Qt does that internally already).

Answer (score 1):

I found out that language list returned by `GetUserPreferredUILanguages()` matters with your "Windows **UI** language" setting, and nothing to do with "Input method list order".

For example, in following screenshot from Win10.21H2,

[image: Win10.21H2 metro UI language setting]

I can see `GetUserPreferredUILanguages()` return a list of three langtags:

```
fr-CA\0fr-FR\0en-US\0\0
```

[image: Check in VC2010 debugger]

In summary, for `GetUserPreferredUILanguages()` and `GetUILanguageFallbackList()` their returned langtag list is determined **solely by** current user's "Windows display language" selection. It is a user-wide single-selection setting. And, for a specific display-language selection, the list-items within and the order of the list-items are hard-coded by Windows itself. Yes, it is even **unrelated** to what "input methods(IME)" you have added to the control panel -- for example, you add "fr-CA" but not "fr-FR", and the fallback list will still be `fr-CA\0fr-FR\0en-US\0\0`.

The difference of the two APIs, according to my experiment, is that `GetUILanguageFallbackList()` returns neutral langtags("fr", "en" etc) as well, so it produces a superset of `GetUserPreferredUILanguages()`.