# How do save the entire content of a binary file into postgres database?

Tags: c++, postgresql

I'm trying to save binary data into postgres. Parts of the code is shown below:

```
string readFile2(const string &fileName)
{
    ifstream ifs(fileName.c_str(), ios::in | ios::binary | ios::ate);
    ifs.seekg(0, ios::end);

    ifstream::pos_type fileSize = ifs.tellg();
    ifs.seekg(0, ios::beg);

    vector<char> bytes(fileSize);
    ifs.read(bytes.data(), fileSize);
    cout.write(bytes.data(),bytes.size());
    cout << "\n";
    cout << fileSize;
    cout << "\n";
    // return bytes.data();
    return string(bytes.data(), fileSize);
}

int main() {
  string content;
  string test = "h";
  char test1 = 'C';
  try {
    cout << "A1 \n";;
    content = readFile2("/var/opt/lizardfs/lib/lizardfs/metadata.mfs");
    pqxx::connection c("postgresql://mark@localhost:26257/metadata");
    pqxx::nontransaction w(c);


    w.exec("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS binary (id INT PRIMARY KEY, meta BLOB)");
    w.exec("INSERT INTO binary (id,meta) VALUES (18, '"+content+"')");
}
```

The problem is that if I try to run the code I get the error:

```
ERROR:  lexical error: unterminated string
DETAIL:  source SQL:
INSERT INTO binary (id,meta) VALUES (18, 'LIZM 2.9
```

I think that is because the next character is a null character. Hexdump shows `00`

If instead of having the `readFile2` function return `return string(bytes.data(), fileSize);` and returns `return bytes.data();` then the error disappears. However, going into the database all I can see is the first few bytes of the binary file, shown below:

```
  id |   meta
-----+-----------
  15 | LIZM 2.9
```

I'm not sure why it's not able to store all the binary content when I have `return bytes.data();`. How do I get the entire content of the binary file to save in the database?

Comment: Have you read the Postgres documentation yet? [Binary Data Types](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/datatype-binary.html) and [BinaryFilesInDB](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/BinaryFilesInDB).

Comment: No not yet, I will read into it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `bytea` instead of `BLOB`, and then escape the binary data when inserting it, eg:

```
w.exec("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS binary (id INT PRIMARY KEY, meta bytea)");
w.exec("INSERT INTO binary (id,meta) VALUES (18, '"+w.esc_raw(content)+"')");
```

Alternatively, put the binary data into a [`pqxx::binarystring`](https://libpqxx.readthedocs.io/en/6.3/a00843.html) instead:

```
pqxx::binarystring bs = content;
w.exec("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS binary (id INT PRIMARY KEY, meta bytea)");
w.exec("INSERT INTO binary (id,meta) VALUES (18, "+w.quote(bs)+")");
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of

```
w.exec("INSERT INTO binary (id,meta) VALUES (18, '"+content+"')");
```

try doing

```
w.exec_params("INSERT INTO binary (id,meta) VALUES ($1, $2)", 18, content);
```

Comment: I get the syntax error ```Error at or near "%": syntax error DETAIL: source SQL: INSERT INTO binary (id,meta) VALUES (%s,%s)```, I copy and pasted.

Comment: @MarkShaio Try instead of `(%s, %s)` using `($1, $2)`. Does it help? If not try `($1::int, $2::bytea)`. And tell me if it helps.

Comment: It's still complaining about the first arguement for some reason.  I did a ```show columns from metadata.binary``` and for the data_type I got ```INT8``` for ```id``` and ```BYTES``` for ```meta```

Comment: @MarkShaio Can you please provide full error that it shows when using `($1, $2)` and when using `($1::int, $2::bytea)`? Also try using different types, e.g. `$2::blob` and `$1::int8`.

Comment: noticed it was my bad, when I added the $1 and $2 I had a typo so there is no  syntax error. But the content is still only showing the first few bytes ```LIZM 2.9```

Comment: @MarkShaio Maybe you're still returning `return bytes.data();` from your read-file function? You have to return `return string(bytes.data(), fileSize);` now to have full-sized file. Because `return bytes.data();` truncates string to first zero byte.

Comment: I just double checked and I have ```return string(bytes.data(), fileSize);```

Comment: I think the key might be to change from ```BLOB``` to ```bytea```

Comment: @MarkShaio I see you accepted another answer. So seems your task is solved. I just wanted to suggest this `exec_params()` syntax because it is very common for all databases when you have short SQL query and pass parameters separately, not encoding them into sql query. It is a common practice to pass params separately. So anyway would be great to learn how to do this correctly when using `libpqxx` library. I'm not an expert of `libpqxx` library that's why I didn't suggest working solution straight away, but I was using postgress from Python a lot, and passing params separately always.

Comment: Thank you Arty, your help was definitely appreciated.