# Saving and reading binary content into postgres

Tags: c++, postgresql

I'm trying to save binary data from a file `metadata.mfs` into the postgres database and then reading from the database, grab the saved binary data and load it into a file. For the purpose of illustrating my goal lets also call it `metadata.mfs` with the same name but in a different directory. When I run `md5sum metadata.mfs` on both files I am expecting to see the same hash. (Essentially I want whatever is saved into the database from file1 be exactly the same as what I extract from the database in file2)

Currently I am not able to achieve that.

Below is what I have so far:

```
string readFile2(const string &fileName)
{
    ifstream ifs(fileName.c_str(), ios::in | ios::binary | ios::ate);
    ifs.seekg(0, ios::end);

    ifstream::pos_type fileSize = ifs.tellg();
    ifs.seekg(0, ios::beg);

    vector<char> bytes(fileSize);
    ifs.read(bytes.data(), fileSize);
    cout.write(bytes.data(),bytes.size());
    cout << "\n";
    cout << fileSize;
    cout << "\n";
    // return bytes.data();
    return string(bytes.data(), fileSize);
}

int main() {
  string content;
  string test = "h";
  char test1 = 'C';
  try {
    cout << "A1 \n";;
    content = readFile2("/var/opt/lizardfs/lib/lizardfs/metadata.mfs");
    pqxx::connection c("postgresql://mark@localhost:26257/metadata");
    pqxx::nontransaction w(c);


    w.exec("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS binary (id INT PRIMARY KEY, meta bytea)");
    w.exec("INSERT INTO binary (id,meta) VALUES (18, '"+w.esc_raw(content)+"')");
    
    pqxx::result r = w.exec("SELECT meta FROM binary WHERE id='18'");
    std::ofstream outfile("metadata.mfs");
    for (auto row: r) {
        cout << row[0] << endl;
        outfile << row[0] << endl;
    }
    outfile.close();
    w.commit()
}
```

The problem is that `cout.write(bytes.data(),bytes.size());` prints out exactly the same as what I would see in the linux terminal if I run `cat metadata.mfs`, but from `cout << row[0] << endl` I see everything in hex, ie, `\x4c495a4d20322e39000021...`.

I suspect this is because I am using `w.esc_raw()` on the binary content before inserting into postgres. Does that mean I need to unescape, ie using `w.unesc_raw()` after extracting the binary data from the database? But how would I do that? I've been looking at the docs here: https://libpqxx.readthedocs.io/en/6.1.1/a00225.html

Comment: Use *placeolder values* and skip this injection stuff entirely. In other words [this section](https://libpqxx.readthedocs.io/en/6.1.1/a01408.html) of the docs.

Comment: I'll do that but I don't think that is the source of my problem. It has to do with the data being binary as I don't have a problem when the file content is just text

Comment: Putting binary junk in the middle of a query is asking for trouble, if not misery. It's best avoided. Use placeholders. Package the data separately. This side-steps a lot of issues, especially UTF-8 encoding related. Is this a binary `BLOB` column?

Comment: Remember, if you're stuck and have literally no other option, then you *must* escape, and do it in a way that's compatible with your encoding. This is *only* relevant when making a query. Any results you get will be handed over by the driver in whatever form is appropriate. There is never a need to "unescape" it, at least not with any driver worth using.

Comment: Very similar from a few hours ago can you explain the difference ?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66845340/how-do-save-the-entire-content-of-a-binary-file-into-postgres-database

Comment: @MarkShaio did you not read the documentation I pointed you to in your earlier question? In particular, https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/datatype-binary.html, which says: "*The `bytea` type supports two external formats for input and output: PostgreSQL's historical "escape" format, and "hex" format. Both of these are always accepted on input. **The output format depends on the configuration parameter `bytea_output`; the default is hex**.*" So yes, you need to unescape the query results when reading the binary field.