# Why is .c_str() not adding '\0' at the end of a string?

Tags: c++, c-strings

When running this code I get `"Hello Worldaaa"`, but according to the job of the `.c_str()` function, the `string a` should be `"Hello World\0"` and `string b` should be `"Hello World\0aaa"` so `"aaa"` should not show up in the output.

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>

using namespace std; 

int main()
{
    string a = "Hello World";
    a = a.c_str();
    string b = a + string("aaa");

    cout << b;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: _["Returns a pointer to a null-terminated character array with data equivalent to those stored in the string."](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/c_str)_ It does, but using it in the `std::string operator+(const char*, const std::string&)` ignores the terminating `'\0'` character to produce the result.

Comment: it's not  actually `.c_str()`, it's actually the constructor that's confusing you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you construct a std::string with an embedded null?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/164168/how-do-you-construct-a-stdstring-with-an-embedded-null)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you are right regarding
[std::string::c_str](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/c_str).

Indeed,

> Returns a pointer to a null-terminated character array with data equivalent to those stored in the string.

However, there are a few considerations which probably misleading you.

---

First of all, the statement:

```
a = a.c_str();
```

is *semantically* a *no-operation*.
You get the `const char*` (i.e. `"Hello World\0"`) and assign it to `a`.
However `a` is a `std::string`, it is a class designed to abstract a "string type" in C++. It handles automatically the `'\0'`, transparently. The user is not supposed to care about the managing of it<sup>1</sup>.

The trick is inside [`std::string::operator=(const char*)`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator%3D).

> Replaces the contents with those of **null-terminated** character string pointed to by s **as if by assign(s, Traits::length(s))**.

---

The last point, about [string concatenation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator%2B).

```
a + string("aaa");
```

As previously, in this case, the operator `std::string::operator+` will handle the `'\0'`.

Shortly, it behaves like:

```
"Hello World\0" + "aaa\0"  ===> "Hello Worldaaa\0"
```

It will care about the "inner `'\0'`" returning a conforming null-terminated string.

---

<sup>1</sup> Unless he/she is playing with the internal memory.

Comment: Really, the point needs to be made that in a "NUL-terminated string", the NUL terminator is not considered part of the *string's data*. It is merely an end-of-string indicator. That is, `"Hello World"` is a different string from `"Hello World\0"`; the latter has an embedded NUL character which is part of the actual string.

Answer (score 0):

That would be unintuitive. Remember that the terminating null character wasn't explicitly used by the user. Syntax of the language added it.

It will create a lot of confusion if the result of `"abcd" + "xyz"` ends up being `"abcd\0xyz"` instead of the intuitive result - `"abcdxyz"`.

In C and C++, concatenating two strings implies ignoring the terminating null character of the first string in the resultant string. Take a look at the documentation of [`strcat`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strcat). It is explicit about the null character while the documentation of `std::string::operator+` isn't.

Comment: The really interesting part is what would be the workaround to store the ``\0`` character explicitely in a `std::string`.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ, I am sure people with a more computer science/programming language theory bent of mind have thought about it. Not me.

Comment: [Yes they did](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/164168/how-do-you-construct-a-stdstring-with-an-embedded-null)

Answer (score 0):

Not quite...

Let's take a look at this line:

```
a = a.c_str();
```

You have an `std::string` that you're trying to assign a `const char*` to. So you'll be using overload (3) of [the `std::string` assignment operator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator%3D). But this doesn't magically change the type of `a`. In other words, we still have an `std::string`!

So that line doesn't actually modify the value of `a` at all.

Then you use the [`operator+`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator%2B) to add two `std::string`'s together. This will result in another `std::string` that is the first with the second appended, which is exactly what you have!

It's not clear to me what you're trying to accomplish here, but if you created a c-string with those values:

```
const char cstr[] = "Hello World\0aaa";
```

And tried to print it, you'd see exactly what you're expecting.